# How can I detect the last iteration in a loop over std::map?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, maps

I'm trying to figure out the best way to determine whether I'm in the last iteration of a loop over a map in order to do something like the following:

```
for (iter = someMap.begin(); iter != someMap.end(); ++iter) {
    bool last_iteration;
    // do something for all iterations
    if (!last_iteration) {
        // do something for all but the last iteration
    }
}
```

There seem to be several ways of doing this: random access iterators, the `distance` function, etc. What's the canonical method?

Edit: no random access iterators for maps!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Canonical? I can't claim that, but I'd suggest

```
final_iter = someMap.end();
--final_iter;
if (iter != final_iter) ...
```

**Edited** to correct as suggested by **[KTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151046/c-last-loop-iteration-stl-map-iterator#151104).** (Thanks! Sometimes you go too quick and mess up on the simplest things...)

Comment: Decrement must be a predecrement or the finalIter will be end.

Comment: CAVEAT: It requires bi-directional iterators, so it doesn't work in all STL collection classes.

Comment: You could just compare with the value at rbegin()

Comment: @ffpf, you can't because comparisons between forward iterators and reverse iterators don't work.

Comment: One can compare against --(someMap.rbegin().base()), but that's just making it over complicated for no good reason. (It was what had originally thought to post LOL :D)

Comment: Of course, doh! I admit it's been a wee while since my last major C++ work. Amazing how quickly things leave the brain when they're not used.

Comment: Unless the map changes inside the loop, final_iter should be evaluated outside it.  In this case, the map must be checked for emptiness, lest we run into the feared undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 24):

Since C++11, you can also use std::next()

```
   for (auto iter = someMap.begin(); iter != someMap.end(); ++iter) { 
        // do something for all iterations
        if (std::next(iter) != someMap.end()) {
            // do something for all but the last iteration
        }
    }
```

Although the question was asked a while ago, I thought it would be worth sharing.

Answer (score 14):

This seems like the simplest:

```
bool last_iteration = iter == (--someMap.end());
```

Comment: Do iterators actually define arithmetic plus with integers?  I didn't think so; but even if some of them do, I'm certain you couldn't rely on it for *every* container.

Comment: This doesn't work... there's no match for the [iterator type] + int operator!

Comment: Bi-directional iterators (what map has) does not have + defined to manipulate it.

Comment: Is decrementing an iterator to an empty collection defined?

Comment: @Tim: If it's an empty collection we'll never enter the loop body. :-)

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to use a ForwardIterator, this should work:

```
for ( i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); ) {
        iterator cur = i++;
        // do something, using cur
        if ( i != c.end() ) {
                // do something using cur for all but the last iteration
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Modified Mark Ransom's so it actually work as intended.

```
finalIter = someMap.end();
--finalIter;
if (iter != final_iter)
```

Answer (score 6):

Surprised no one mentioned it yet, but of course boost has something  ;)

[Boost.Next](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#functions_next_prior) (and the equivalent Boost.Prior)

Your example would look like:

```
for (iter = someMap.begin(); iter != someMap.end(); ++iter) {
    // do something for all iterations
    if (boost::next(iter) != someMap.end()) {
        // do something for all but the last iteration
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is in the standard library as `std::next`, etc. now.

Answer (score 3):

The following code would be optimized by a compiler so that to be the best solution for this task by performance as well as by OOP rules:

```
if (&*it == &*someMap.rbegin()) {
    //the last iteration
}
```

This is the best code by OOP rules because std::map has got a special member function rbegin for the code like:

```
final_iter = someMap.end();
--final_iter;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why to work to find the EOF so that you dont give something to it.

**Simply, exclude it;**

```
for (iter = someMap.begin(); someMap.end() - 1; ++iter) {
    //apply to all from begin to second last element
}
```

**KISS (KEEP IT SIMPLY SIMPLE)**

Comment: Are you sure this works? Do iterators define `operator-` with `int`s?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace boost::lambda;

// call the function foo on each element but the last...
if( !someMap.empty() )
{
  std::for_each( someMap.begin(), --someMap.end(), bind( &Foo, _1 ) );
}
```

Using std::for_each will ensure that the loop is tight and accurate... Note the introduction of the function foo() which takes a single argument (the type should match what is contained in someMap). This approach has the added addition of being 1 line. Of course, if Foo is really small, you can use a lambda function and get rid of the call to &Foo.

Comment: This doesn't allow to "do something for all iterations"

Answer (score 1):

How about this, no one mentioning but...

```
for (iter = someMap.begin(); iter != someMap.end(); ++iter) {
    // do something for all iterations
    if (iter != --someMap.end()) {
        // do something for all but the last iteration
    }
}
```

this seems simple, mm...

Answer (score 1):

For someone who likes C++11 range-based loop:

```
    for (const auto& pair : someMap) {
      if (&pair != &*someMap.rbegin()) ...
    }
```

Notice only reference type works here, not `auto pair`

Comment: This answer is of some interest to me because I too like the C++11 loop. But it seems to call for the result of '&' in the address-of sense to behave consistently between taking the address of the variable `pair` and taking the address of the result of `*someMap.rbegin()`. The value of `const auto& pair` is based on begin()..end() rather than rend()..rbegin() so it seems one could be skeptical that this is valid across compilers and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, yet effective, approach:

```
  size_t items_remaining = someMap.size();

  for (iter = someMap.begin(); iter != someMap.end(); iter++) {
    bool last_iteration = items_remaining-- == 1;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

void process(int ii)
{
   std::cout << " " << ii;
}

int main(void)
{
   std::list<int> ll;

   ll.push_back(1);
   ll.push_back(2);
   ll.push_back(3);
   ll.push_back(4);
   ll.push_back(5);
   ll.push_back(6);

   std::list<int>::iterator iter = ll.begin();
   if (iter != ll.end())
   {
      std::list<int>::iterator lastIter = iter;
      ++ iter;
      while (iter != ll.end())
      {
         process(*lastIter);
         lastIter = iter;
         ++ iter;
      }
      // todo: think if you need to process *lastIter
      std::cout << " | last:";
      process(*lastIter);
   }

   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

This program yields:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 | last: 6
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my optimized take:

```
iter = someMap.begin();

do {
    // Note that curr = iter++ may involve up to three copy operations
    curr = iter;

    // Do stuff with curr

    if (++iter == someMap.end()) {
        // Oh, this was the last iteration
        break;
    }

    // Do more stuff with curr

} while (true);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just pull an element out of the map prior to iteration, then perform your "last iteration" work out of the loop and then put the element back *into* the map.  This is horribly bad for asynchronous code, but considering how bad the rest of C++ is for concurrency, I don't think it'll be an issue.  :-)

Comment: Maps ARE ordered - maybe you're thinking of a hash?

Comment: I was under the impression that Maps were implemented by default using hashtables.  I will correct the answer.  Thanks!