# What's the most elegant way to concatenate a list of values with delimiter in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have never found a neat(er) way of doing the following.

Say I have a list/array of strings.

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

And I want to concatenate them into a single string delimited by a comma as follows:

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl
```

In Java, if I write something like this (pardon the syntax),

```
String[] list = new String[] {"abc","def","ghi","jkl"};
String str = null;
for (String s : list)
{
   str = str + s + "," ;
}

System.out.println(str);
```

I'll get

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl,  //Notice the comma in the end
```

So I have to rewrite the above for loop as follows

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
   str = str + list[i];
   if (i != list.length - 1)
   {
     str = str + ",";
   }
}
...
```

Can this be done in a more elegant way in Java?

I would certainly use a StringBuilder/Buffer for efficiency, but I wanted to illustrate the case in point without being too verbose. By elegant, I mean a solution that avoids the ugly(?) `if` check inside the loop.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205555/the-most-sophisticated-way-for-creating-comma-separated-strings-from-a-collection/205712#205712

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285523

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my version: [Java Tricks: Fastest Way to Collecting Objects in a String](http://blog.pdark.de/2008/07/11/fastest-way-to-collecting-objects-in-a-string/)

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder ();
String delim = "";
for (Object o: list)
{
    buffer.append (delim);
    delim = ", "; // Avoid if(); assignment is very fast!
    buffer.append (o);
}
buffer.toString ();
```

As an additional bonus: If your code in the loop is more complex, then this approach will produce a correct results without complex `if()`s.

Also note that with modern CPUs, the assignment will happen only in the cache (or probably only in a register).

Conclusion: While this code looks odd at first glance, it has many advantages.

Comment: It is not very pretty - make an initialization of delim every iteration.

Comment: Please provide your solution in case of deletion of your blog post.

Comment: +1 This is what I do also. Do you have performance figures to prove we are right?

Comment: @Gonzo: if() is slower than an assign. The assignment is just a pointer operation and it always happens with the same address, so the CPU will probably use registers and keep everything in the cache. Also, the code is compact, the setup is constant (no need to do part of the work outside of the loop) and the code in the loop is always the same.

Comment: Talking about this degree of performance modifications is ridiculous anyway. Isn't it? Well, then show me a usecase where you need to squeeze out this extra nanosecond ...

Comment: I just did a quick performance test. Statistically speaking, there is no difference whatsoever.

Really, an if() is slow?

Comment: @Aaron: I'll agree it's more compact. Faster, no. Even if you were writing in direct assembly, that's not going to make a difference. Furthermore, smart compilers will unroll and optimize it anyways.

Comment: ... but to speak of clean code: using `builder.setLength(builder.length() - 1);` after the loop is probably the cleanest (and doesn't require a `System.arraycopy(..)` like `deleteCharAt(int)` does)

Comment: @KLE: No but since my loop doesn't contain conditional code, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @sfussenegger: It might cause the buffer to allocate more memory because that single character doesn't fit which means you have an `arraycopy`.

Comment: @Gonzo: if() means a branch and that always costs more, even if you don't notice a difference in runtime. At the very best, the CPU branch prediction hardware must run which at least costs power, leading to heat, leading to premature aging of your CPU. ;) Run this code with Java 1.1 and on a Pentium CPU and it still performs. Run it on a Netbook. Also, the code is very clear, readable and obvious and it's very similar in any language.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: I was comparing setLength(builder.length() - 1) to deleteCharAt(builder.length()) which are doing the same but the former with far less overhead. You're right that an extra character might cause an extra arraycopy - but chances are minimal, especially for Strings of a size where speed really matters (size of the underlying buffer always doubles). But still it's ridiculous to talk about performance at this level anyway. I really don't care if my CPU dies 5 minutes earlier as it wasn't able to predict branches right. Damn, if it wasn't able to do so it deserved it anyway! ;)

Comment: @St.Shadow: No, it isn't a performance bug. Because the string litteral in the string pool. It isn't allocation new heap memory. The only operation that happens is simply assigning the variable to a pointer (which points to the string pool).

Comment: If is quite slow, it causes a brance prediction where it has to guess which way the code is going to branch and fill the cache based on that guess, if it guesses wrong it has to go out and refetch the cach, but even this is silly to worry about since things like this change with CPU & java version.  Becoming an expert at optimization means your expertiese will be outdated and probably wrong in two years.

Answer (score 11):

Using [Guava's (formerly google-collections) joiner class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html):

```
Joiner.on(",").join(list)
```

Done.

Comment: +1 for google-collections. Yes, yes, I know -- 'an external dependency just for string joining?!?!' -- but it can make your code so much shorter + more expressive that, if you learn the API, it will pay for itself in an hour. :)

Comment: once you take a look at the api, you will use ist for much more than just string joining.

Comment: You right - if external api can be used more that one time - it is best solution.

Comment: @Thorbjorn: see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeO_J2OcHYM and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ni_KEkHfto for an in-depth explanation why you should use G-C. it simplifies a lot of the boilerplate when using almost any complex data structure in java.

Comment: why this is cool: now you want to skip over nulls? Just insert '.skipNulls()' between the 'on' and 'join' calls.  Or treat nulls like empty strings? Easy, that's '.useForNull("")'. Etc.

Comment: Cool - didn't know of this before. Time to throw away our own `StringUtils.join()` utility... :)

Answer (score 3):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String st: list) {
    builder.append(st).append(',');
}
builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length());
String result = builder.toString();
```

Do not use '+' for string contacenations. It`s slow.

Answer (score 2):

Look here:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/91

for a full discussion of this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am looking for a more elegant approach (perhaps one that involves fewer lines of code). Performance, in my case, is not such a major concern.

Comment: I don not like checks in the look when you can do it outside

Answer (score 2):

I'd bet that there are several classes named "StringUtil", "StringsUtil", "Strings" or anything along those lines on the classpath of any medium sized Java project. Most likely, any of them will provide a join function. Here are some examples I've found in my project:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(...)
org.apache.wicket.util.string.Wicket.join(...)
org.compass.core.util.StringUtils.arrayToDelimitedString(...)
```

As you might want to get rid of some external dependencies in the future, you may want to to something like this:

```
public static final MyStringUtils {
    private MyStringUtils() {}

    public static String join(Object[] list, String delim) {
        return org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(list, delim);
    }
}
```

Now that's what I call "elegant" ;)

Comment: Why would you create a new class just to wrap a call to org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join? How does that remove the external dependencies?

Comment: @DerekSpringer it doesn't remove the external dependency. Hiding the dependency in something like MyStringUtils only makes it easier to change the implementation. As a consequence, one could remove the external dependency by changing MyStringUtils class only.

Answer (score 0):

check if this is useful:

```
List<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(3);
    numbers.add(4);
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(6);
    String str = " ";
    for(Integer s:numbers){
    str=str+s+" , ";
    }
    System.out.println(str.substring(0,str.length()-2));
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use a `StringBuffer` to implement this feature. `String` is immutable so everytime you concat two `String`s, a new object is created.

More efficient is the use of `StringBuffer`:

```
String[] list = new String[] {"abc","def","ghi","jkl"};
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
for (String s : list) {
   str.append(s);
   str.append(",");
}
str.deleteCharAt(str.length());
System.out.println(str); //automatically invokes StringBuffer.toString();
```

Comment: You shouldn't use StringBuffer where it's not necessary, it's thread safe and slow, i would use StringBuilder instead. You also have to delete the last comma

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++) {
    str = str + list[i];
    str = str + ",";    
}
str = str + list[list.length-1]
```

Comment: Using string concatination isn't very fast. This code is also hard to read i think

Comment: i know string concatenation isent fast thats not the point and yes its less readable just pointing out other options to do what the OP asked