# Storing in String

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the most elegant way to concatenate a list of values with delimiter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642159/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-concatenate-a-list-of-values-with-delimiter-in-jav)

I have 3 different words listed in property file in 3 different lines. 
QWERT
POLICE
MATTER

I want to read that property file and store those 3 words in String, not in aarylist separated by whitespace. The output should look like this
String str = { QWERT POLICE MATTER}

Now I used the follwoing code and getting the output without white space in between the words: 
String str = {QWERTPOLICEMATTER}. What should I do to the code to get the string result with words separated by whitespace.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("abc.properties");
            pro.load(in);
            Enumeration em = pro.keys();
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (em.hasMoreElements()){
               String str = (String)em.nextElement();
               search = (stringBuffer.append(pro.get(str)).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
search = (stringBuffer.append(" ").append(pro.get(str)).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append a blank space in your loop. See the extra append below:

```
while (em.hasMoreElements()){
    String str = (String)em.nextElement();
    search = (stringBuffer.append(pro.get(str)).toString());
    if(em.hasNext()){
        stringBuffer.append(" ")
    }
}
```