# Solution critique: reversing words in a sentence

Tags: java, algorithm

I had a technical interview and was given the following question:

> Write a function that takes a sentence and returns the sentence with the words in reverse order (i.e. "hello world" becomes "world hello").

Here is the solution that I gave in Java:

```
/** Takes a sentence as an input and returns the sentence with the words in
 *  reversed order. */
private static String reverseSentence(String sentence) {
    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");
    String reversedString = "";
    for (int k = words.length - 1; k >= 0; k -= 1) {
        reversedString += " " + words[k];
    }
    return reversedString.substring(1);
}
```

I got to thinking that there has to be a more efficient way to solve this problem than this. I don't see this being asked in a technical interview for a top company if this solution turns out to be the best one and there isn't one more efficient/elegant.

Can anyone think of a better way to do this?

Comment: Ya.. Use a `StringBuilder` instead of `String reversedString`. String concatenation (especially within a loop) isn't efficient.

Comment: There is a `Collections.reverse` method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List) you can probably make use of it.

Comment: what if hello<tab>world? What if my string contains just a space? Although i wasn't the interviewer there but they certainly look for exception/edge case handling.

Comment: @almasshaikh `\s` matches any whitespace character: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`

Comment: Yes but will you get back \t when you reverse?

Comment: @almasshaikh good point, then the string needs to be split at word limits.

Comment: Always ask about the use case before delving in with an answer. There's often a trade-off between speed and maintainability.

Comment: @SirDarius - What almas is trying to say is - "irrespective of the number of spaces present, the OP is always adding only one space.." :)

Comment: @SirDarius Yes that's the way but before running the horses, i always tend to ask the question to interviewer like is it really going to be a space seperated string?

Comment: If you improve your solution to use `StringBuilder` and preserve whitespaces, make sure to initialize the `StringBuilder` with an initial capacity of `sentence.length()`. That way you avoid resizing of the internal buffer (which is amortized constant time, but still needless since you know the exact length of the result).

Answer (score 1):

Here are better ways to concatenate the elements of the sentence: [What's the most elegant way to concatenate a list of values with delimiter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642159/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-concatenate-a-list-of-values-with-delimiter-in-ja/1642169#1642169)

Also, `sentence.split("\\s+")` only works when the input is clean (people do make typos). There is also the questions what should happen to punctuation. `World! Hello,` does look very odd.

Comment: `String.join` is a good choice, too. Even if it might not be quite as efficient, it's "out of the box".

Answer (score 0):

Except the comment, to use a more efficient data structure (StringBuilder) to create the string, I don't think there is much you can do. The time complexity to reverse an array is `n/2` ([How do I reverse an int array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)) but afterwards you would still need to concatenate all of the items, which should be `n` - since you're concatenating them right away you get down from `3n/2` to only `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have reversed the array by swapping references (0 with length-1, etc) you can

```
String reversedSentence = String.join( " ", words );
```

But I think it is better to avoid a String array.

```
String s = "the quick brown fox";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int p = s.length();
int np = -1;
while( (np = s.lastIndexOf( " ", p-1 )) != -1 ){
    sb.append( s.substring( np + 1, p ) ).append( " " );
    p = np; 
}
sb.append( s.substring( 0, p ) );
System.out.println( sb.toString() );
```

This assumes that the input string is properly "normalized".

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this question is asked with a constraint asking for it to be done without using any extra memory.

One answer to this modified question is:

1. First reverse each word in the sentence ("Hello World" -> "olleH dlroW")
2. Then reverse the entire sentence ("olleH dlroW" -> "World Hello")