# removing comma from string array

Tags: java, sql

I want to execute a query like
 select ID from "xyz_DB"."test" where user in ('a','b')

so the corresponding code is like

```
String s="(";
for(String user:selUsers){
    s+= " ' " + user + " ', ";
}
s+=")";
```

Select ID from test where userId in s;

The following code is forming the value of s as ('a','b',)
i want to remove the comma after the end of array how to do this ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do this:

```
String s = "(";
boolean first = true;
for(String user : selUsers){
    if (first) {
        first = false;
    } else {
        s += ", ";
    }
    s += " ' " + user + " '";
}
s += ")";
```

But it is more efficient to use a StringBuilder to assemble a String if there is looping involved.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
boolean first = true;
for(String user : selUsers){
    if (first) {
        first = false;
    } else {
        sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.append(" ' ").append(user).append(" '");
}
sb.append(")");
String s = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

This does the trick.

```
String s = "";
for(String user : selUsers)
    s += ", '" + user + "'";

if (selUsers.size() > 0)
    s = s.substring(2);

s = "(" + s + ")";
```

But, a few pointers:

- When concatenating strings like this, you are advised to work with `StringBuilder` and `append`.
- If this is part of an SQL-query, you probably want to **sanitize the user-names**. See [xkcd: Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/) for an explanation.

---

For fun, a variation of Stephen C's answer:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
boolean first = true;
for(String user : selUsers){
    if (!first || (first = false))
        sb.append(", ");
    sb.append('\'').append(user).append('\'');
}
sb.append(')');
```

you could even do the loop it like this :-)

```
for(String user : selUsers)
    sb.append(!first || (first=false) ? ", \'" : "\'").append(user).append('\'');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'old style' of loop where you have the index, then you add the comma on every username except the last:

```
    String[] selUsers = {"a", "b", "c"};
    String s="("; 
    for(int i = 0; i < selUsers.length; i++){
        s+= " ' " + selUsers[i] + " ' ";  
        if(i < selUsers.length -1){
            s +=" , ";
        }
    }
    s+=")";
```

But as others already mentioned, use StringBuffer when concatenating strings:

```
    String[] selUsers = {"a", "b", "c"};
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("("); 
    for(int i = 0; i < selUsers.length; i++){
        s.append(" ' " + selUsers[i] + " ' ");  
        if(i < selUsers.length -1){
            s.append(" , ");
        }
    }
    s.append(")");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`StringUtils.join`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Iterable,%20char)) from apache commons.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to adding the trailing ')' I'd strip off the last character of the string if it's a comma, or perhaps just replace the trailing comma with a right parenthesis - in pseudo-code, something like

```
if s.last == ',' then
  s = s.left(s.length() - 1);
end if;

s = s + ')';
```

or

```
if s.last == ',' then
  s.last = ')';
else
  s = s + ')';
end if;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

i would do `s+= " ,'" + user + "'";` (place the comma before the value) and add a counter to the loop where i just do `s = "'" + user + "'";` if the counter is `1` (or `0`, depending on where you start to count).

Comment: @sarah, I think my answer clarifies his suggestion.

Comment: as aioobe says, see his answer for some code. i wanted you to think yourself, not giving you the premade code, so you realy understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

(N.B. - I'm not a Java guy, so the syntax may be wrong here - apologies if it is).

If `selUsers` is an array, why not do:

`selUsers.join(',');`

This should do what you want.

**EDIT:**

Looks like I was wrong - I figured Java had this functionality built-in. Looks like the Apache project has something that does what I meant, though. Check out this SO answer: [Java: function for arrays like PHP's join()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join/1515450#1515450)

Comment: No `join` method exists on arrays or collections in Java.

Comment: Yeah, -sort of- unfortunately Java is purely OO language with no to little functional capabilities which `join` is one of.

Comment: @Esko - no that's not the reason.  There's nothing non-OO about a `join` method.  I guess that the real reason it is not supported is that arrays were deliberately kept simple.

Comment: @Stephen `join` is an operation applies to lists, not a property of list. Being OO can be seen as encapsulating based on what belongs to whom and since operations are implementation details instead of properties, they're not exactly at home in OO designed libraries such as Java Collections. Note that I'm not saying this would be a specifically good thing...

Comment: @Esko - oh I see what you mean.  But even so, the real reason there is no `join` is that "they" didn't think it was important enough.  Java is a LONG WAY from being a pure OO language, and "they" have no compunction in adding non-OO helper methods / classes if they are useful.  BTW: calling `join` a "functional capability" is a bit of a stretch too.  It would be just another method in `Arrays`.  Actually, a secondary reason is that they'd have to add overloads for each primitive type ... because of the **non-OO** way that Java's handles primitive types!

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.4+

```
s = s.replaceFirst("\\, \\)$", ")");
```

**Edited:** I forgot last space before parethesis

Answer (score 0):

I fully support [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003474/removing-comma-from-string-array/3003539#3003539)'s answer - that's the one I wanted to suggest aswell: simply avoid adding the additional comma.

But in your special case, the following should work too:

```
s = s.replace(", \\)", ")");
```

It simply replaces the substring `", )"` with a single bracket `")"`.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder has a perfectly good [append(int)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(int)) overload.

```
String [] array = {"1","2","3" ...}; 
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
 builder.append(s + "( ")
for(String i : array) 
{ 
    if(builder.length() != 0) 
        builder.append(","); 
    builder.append(i); 
} 
builder.append(" )")
```

Answer shamelessly copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285523/last-iteration-of-for-loop-in-java/285544#285544)