# velocity: do something except in last loop iteration

Tags: java, loops, iteration, velocity

In velocity, I want to do something different in the last loop.

What is the correct idiom?

**RELATED**: [Last iteration of enhanced for loop in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285523/last-iteration-of-for-loop-in-java)

Comment: @ratchet: same as related question: I am concatenating things with a separator in between and don't want to put the separator after the last item

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use a test if you are in last iteration::

```
#foreach( $item in $list )
    $item.text #if( $foreach.hasNext ), #end
#end
```

Answer (score 19):

@soulcheck's answer is what you need, but be aware that the `$foreach` variable is only available in velocity 1.7, if you're using an earlier version you can use:

```
#foreach( $item in $list )
    $item.text #if( $velocityHasNext ), #end
#end
```

However, the `$velocityHasNext` variable is deprecated in versions 1.7 and removed in 2.0 in favour of `$foreach.hasNext`.

Comment: At the time of writing, there is no version 2.0 of Velocity.

Answer (score 8):

The idiom I use is to save the optional text to be added if the loop doesn't finish.

```
#set($sep = "")    
#foreach($item in $list)
 $sep$item
 #set($sep = ", ")
#end
```

Comment: How would I solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713626/velocity-template-loop-through-array-to-create-string ?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in an older version of Velocity

```
#if($velocityCount < $list.size()), #end
```