# velocity template loop through array to create string

Tags: velocity, aws-appsync, vtl

I'm trying to use the `velocity templating language` in an `AWS appsync resolver` to create a string by looping through an array of characters.

Given the array `listOfWords = ["好" "克力"]` how would I achieve the string output of `queryString = "+\"好\" +\"克力\""`

So far I have managed something like this:

```
24: #set($listOfWords = ["好" "克力"])
25: #set($queryString = "")
26: #foreach($word in $listOfWords)
27:   #if( $velocityCount == 1 )
28:     #set($queryString = "+\"$word\"")
29:   #else
30:     #set($queryString = $queryString +"+\"$word\"")
31:   #end
32: #end
```

This returns the error:
`Encountered \"$word\" at velocity[line 28, column 37]\nWas expecting one of:\n    <RPAREN> ...\n    <WHITESPACE> ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    \"+\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    \"/\" ...\n    \"%\" ...\n    <LOGICAL_AND> ...\n    <LOGICAL_OR> ...\n    <LOGICAL_LT> ...\n    <LOGICAL_LE> ...\n    <LOGICAL_GT> ...\n    <LOGICAL_GE> ...\n    <LOGICAL_EQUALS> ...\n    <LOGICAL_NOT_EQUALS> ...\n`

I have also tried

```
#foreach( $word in $listOfWords )
        #if( $velocityCount == 1 )
            #set($queryString = "+" + "\\" + "\"" + $word + "\\" + "\"") line 27
        #else
            #set($queryString = $queryString + "+" + "\\" + "\"" + $word + "\\" + "\"")
        #end
    #end
    )
```

But seem to be causing a lexical error:

`"Lexical error,   Encountered: \"\\\"\" (34), after : \"\\\\\\\\\" at *unset*[line 27, column 64]"`

Comment: could you put the line numbers in your example so we can see where line 28 is?

Comment: sorry, missed that. Added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that:

```
#set($listOfWords = ["好" "克力"])
#set($q = '"')
#set($queryString = "")
#foreach($word in $listOfWords)
  #if( $velocityCount == 1 )
    #set($queryString = "$q$word$q")
  #else
    #set($queryString = "$queryString+$q$word$q")
  #end
#end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than building up a VTL variable, you could just build up the string as the output directly. Kind of like this example from the VTL docs;

```
<ul>
  #foreach( $product in $allProducts )
    <li>$product</li>
  #end
</ul>
```