# How to check if processing the last item in an Iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

If I have an iterator and I want to check the last value, how can I check it? Like

```
private Set<String> saarcCountries = new TreeSet<String>();
Iterator iter = saarcCountries.iterator();

while(iter.hasNext()) {

    String name = (String)iter.next();
    int countryId = Integer.parseInt(name);

    newsOrAnnouncementInsert.add(newsId);
    newsOrAnnouncementInsert.add(countryId);
    newsOrAnnouncementInsert.add(1);            //addby

    if (!(last value in iterator))) {
        newsOrAnnouncementInsert.add("~!~");//Delimiter for Multiple Detail Records
    }//end if

} //end of while
```

How can I check for last value.  what should replace **last value in iterator**?

Comment: Check out this one as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285523/last-iteration-of-for-loop-in-java

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can check it just like you do in the `while` condition:

```
if ( ! iter.hasNext()) {
    // last iteration
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 35):

If `iter.hasNext()` is false *after* `iter.next()` then it is the last item.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 13):

This answer is not specific to an Iterator, but can be used for any iterating statement where you need to insert a separator between items. It doesn't need to know the current index nor does it need any condition.

```
String previousSeparator = "";
for (String value : collection) {
  System.err.println(previousSeparator + value);
  previousSeparator = ",";
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple. I wonder why that common problem doesn't have a standard solution? It probably has in one of the many libraries, I just don't know it.

Answer (score 3):

Although other answers gave some ideas, I think it is better to add it without the condition and remove the last delimiter after the while loop terminates.

Comment: "Ewwwww!" This just makes me think of horrid string joining support in java :(

Comment: @pst - Maybe, but I try to avoid branches when I can.

Answer (score 3):

Use [StrBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrBuilder.html) (an [apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) class) as the type of newsOrAnnouncementInsert.  Then use the `StrBuilder.appendSeperator()` method.

For example

```
StrBuilder newsOrAnnouncementInsert = new StrBuilder();

while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    newsOrAnnouncementInsert.appendSeperator("~!~");

    String name = (String)iter.next();
    int countryId = Integer.parseInt(name);

    newsOrAnnouncementInsert.add(newsId);
    newsOrAnnouncementInsert.add(countryId);
    newsOrAnnouncementInsert.add(1);
}
```

`appendSeperator` only adds the seperator if the buffer is not currently empty (in this case, if this is the first time through the loop).

Basically, you want to invert the comparison.  Don't check to see if you are on the last element of the itnerator, instead check to see that you are not processing the first element.  If not the first element, append the seperator then append the current element.

Comment: Thanks but i need a library for using **StrBuilder**. Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

This question is old, the answer is good, but I used this answer to figure out how to add commas between list items and add an end of list delimiter. In case someone else like me is looking for the same thing here's what I did:

```
public String toString() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("List contains:\n");

    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); 

    while(iterator.hasNext()){

        // Get the next element.
        sb.append(iterator.next());

        // If there is another element add a comma.
        if(iterator.hasNext()){
            sb.append(", ");
        }else{
            sb.append(" ~!~");
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if (!(iter.hasNext())) {
    newsOrAnnouncementInsert.add("~!~");//Delimiter for Multiple Detail Records
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hasNext` method to check if this is the last value. If you don't have any next values, this means it is the last value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the Iterator you can use this approach.

```
boolean afterFirst = false;
for(String name : saarcCountries) {
    if(afterFirst)
       newsOrAnnouncementInsert.add("~!~");
    afterFirst = true;

    newsOrAnnouncementInsert.add(newsId);
    newsOrAnnouncementInsert.add(name);
    newsOrAnnouncementInsert.add(1);
}
```

Say its a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder newsOrAnnouncementInsert = new StringBuidler();
String sep = "";

for(String name : saarcCountries) {
    newsOrAnnouncementInsert.append(sep + newsId + name + 1);
    sep = "~!~";
}
```