# How do I get this for loop to work right?

Tags: java, for-loop

i don't know how to do something specific at the last loop of this for loop:

```
String msg = "---Player List, Count:" + users.size() + "---" + brln;
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
    if((i - 1) == users.size()){
            msg += "--::" + users.get(i).name; //Do this at the last loop
            return; //returns the void
    }
    msg += "--::" + users.get(i).name + brln; // do this by default
}
```

Can you help me get this to work?

Comment: How about only looping for users.size()-1 times and then do your last bit?

Comment: i cant do that because it uses the int from the forloop

Comment: @FFlaser Well.. you know what value that will have though.

Comment: @Duncan exactly since it always the last item! no need for `i`

Comment: Mostly I solve that problem in the same manner as you did. I really would like too see a more elegant way too :-)

Comment: @treeno Check this elegant answer by Jon Skeet [Last Iteration of for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285523/last-iteration-of-for-loop-in-java)

Comment: @gtgaxiola I usually don't do that after the loop because in that case you would need another breakcondition if the list is empty...

Comment: @gtgaxiola `toolkit`'s answere there beats Jon Skeet's.

Comment: Note that you [don't need a special case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21093620/474189).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik right you are! Make the Delimiter change on the loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing it wrong. Change your line:

```
if((i - 1) == users.size())
```

by this one:

```
if(i == (users.size()-1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Your condition is wrong: instead of `(i - 1) == users.size()` use `(i + 1) == users.size()` or `i == users.size() - 1`.

Basically `(i - 1) == users.size()` would match the element after the last (which clearly doesn't exist), i.e. for a list of size 5 you'd get `(i - 1) == 5` or `i == 6`.

In the example above `(i + 1) == users.size()` and `i == users.size() - 1` would resolve to `(i + 1) == 5` and `i == 5 - 1` which both result in `i == 4`, which is the last index in the list.

*Edit:* Btw, your loop is still quite odd. You basically seem to add a line break after each but the last element. Why don't you change it to something like this:

```
String msg = "---Player List, Count:" + users.size() + "---" + brln;
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
  if( i > 0){
    msg += brln;
  }
  msg += "--::" + users.get(i).name;
}
```

This would add a line break before every line except the first. Note how the condition is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you need last index just use `if( i == users.size()-1)`

In the example you provide you should use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for string concatenation. Then you only need to loop without asking anything and you can use `for-each` loop.

```
StringBuilder msg =new StringBuilder().append("---Player List, Count:").append(users.size()).append("---");
for (User user : users) {
   msg.append(brln)
     .append("--::").append(user.name)
     .append(brln);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this 
from:

```
if((i - 1) == users.size()){
```

to:

```
if((i + 1) == users.size()){
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want in effect is a string of entries separated by a delimiter, where the delimiter is a line break. Use this idiom:

```
String delimiter = "", result = "";
for (...loop init...) {
  result += delimiter;
  ...append one entry...
  delimiter = brln;
}
```

Other than that, building a large string by creating new string in each iteration is bad for performance as it is an O(n^2) operation. You should prefer a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your code a little, you can avoid a special case:

```
StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder("---Player List, Count:" + users.size() 
    + "---"); // Note a lack of brln

for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {    
    msg.append(brln + "--::" + users.get(i).name);
}

return msg.toString();
```

Ideally you should use a `StringBuilder` for concatenating strings in a loop, as I've done above.

(*This solution works in your case, since you had a header including a line break. See other solutions for a generic way to insert string X between every occurence but the last in a loop*).

Comment: +1 from me, too. I withdraw my comments above (under the question).

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition to

```
i == users.size() - 1
```

Why? In Java (and other languages) the first element in a list is at index 0, and the last element at N-1 (if N is the number of elements currently in the list), so users.size() - 1 is the index of the last element. For example, if there are 10 elements in users list, the last will be at index 9.

Full code:

```
String msg = "---Player List, Count:" + users.size() + "---" + brln;

for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {

    //if i equals to the last index, do your special handling of the loop
    if(i == (users.size() - 1)) {
        msg += "--::" + users.get(i).name; //Do this at the last loop
        break; 
    }

    msg += "--::" + users.get(i).name + brln; // do this by default
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not help you right now (when you don't use Java 8), all this messy code will have an end with Java 8:

```
// requires Java 8
String msg = users.stream().map(User::name).collect(Collectors.joining(brln));
```

Comment: I guess in time I'll find that more readable. But for now, I look at that and shudder a little.

Comment: Yes, maybe one needs getting used to it first. But what makes me shudder much more is the fact that such a tiny problem makes about 10 people discuss about it! So every simpler, less error prone solution is welcome, I think. ;)