# How can I find last <td> in table with PHP

Tags: php

I wonder how can i find out last  in table with PHP, aka if that  is last then i want to apply different style and content to it.

This is part of my code generating table content.

```
  $content .= '</tr>';

  $totalcols = count ($columns);
  if (is_array ($tabledata))
  {
    foreach ($tabledata as $tablevalues)
    {
      if ($tablevalues[0] == 'dividingline')
      {
        $content .= '<tr><td colspan="' . $totalcols . '" style="background-color:#efefef;"><div align="left"><b>' . $tablevalues[1] . '</b></div></td></tr>';
        continue;
      }
      else
      {
        $content .= '<tr>';
        foreach ($tablevalues as $tablevalue)
        {
          $content .= '<td>' . $tablevalue . '</td>';
        }

        $content .= '</tr>';
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $content .= '<tr><td align="center" style="border-bottom: none;" colspan="' . $totalcols . '">No Records Found</td></tr>';
  }
```

I know there is option to do something like that with jQuery later on, but I don't want to complicate it and just solve it with php at time when i generate table.

Comment: Why do you need this? There might be another way.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244/how-to-determine-the-first-and-last-iteration-in-a-foreach-loop)?

Comment: can you not just count `$tablevalues` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a count:

```
$count = 1;
foreach ($tablevalues as $tablevalue)
{
    $count++;

    if( $count > count( $tablevalues)) {
        echo "Last td tag is up next! ";
    }
    $content .= '<td>' . $tablevalue . '</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can execute any code in last loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($tablevalues);$i++)
{
    $tablevalue=$tablevalues[$i];
    $content .= '<td>' . $tablevalue . '</td>';
    if($i==count($tablevalues)-1){ 
        // last loop execution
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a somehow trick

```
foreach ($tablevalues as $k => $tablevalue)
{
  if ($k==count($tablevalues)-1)
  {
    // last td of current row
    $content .= '<td>' . $tablevalue . '</td>';
  }
  else
  {
    $content .= '<td>' . $tablevalue . '</td>';
  }
}
```

I just hope that your keys of your $tablevalues set match this code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `for($i = 0; i < count($tablevalues); $i++) {}` loop and consider `count($tablevalues)-1` to be the last key of your array.

So that `$tablevalues[count($tablevalues)-1]` is your last `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use jQuery?It has provisions to do something like that.

Comment: Because I can't use jQuery + I rather have it done as it generates.