# php check array index out of bounds

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the following array.

```
$a['a'] = 1;
$a['b'] = 2;
$a['c'] = 3;
$a['d'] = 4;
```

and then i am looping the array

```
foreach( $a as $q => $x )
{

  # Some operations ....

  if( isLastElement == false  ){ 
     #Want to do some more operation
  }
}
```

How can i know that the current position is `last` or not ?

Thanks.

Comment: As your array is not a numeric indexed array, you could use an integer, which is incremented and compared to the `count` of your array

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244/how-to-determine-the-first-and-last-iteration-in-a-foreach-loop#1070256), which recommends using a counter to identify the last element in the looped set.

Comment: @user1073122 its not possible in my specific requirement.

Comment: What is not possible ? `count($a)` will return the number of element in your array, so you can use an integer initialized to 0 before the loop increment it at each loop, and compare it with the count of the array. You will be able to know when you are on the last element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a key of last element & compare.

```
$last_key = end(array_keys($a));

foreach( $a as $q => $x )
{
 # Some operations ....
 if( $q == $last_key){ 
     #Your last element
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (array_slice($a, 0, -1) as $q => $x) {

}
extraProcessing(array_slice($a, -1));
```

EDIT:

I guess the first `array_slice` is not necessary if you want to do the same processing on the last element.  Actually neither is the last.

```
foreach ($a as $q => $x) {

}
extraProcessing($q, $x);
```

The last elements are still available after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function for this operation.

Comment: The `end()` call would have to go outside the loop as it gets the last value and sets the internal pointer to it rather than checking for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a['a'] = 1;
$a['b'] = 2;
$a['c'] = 3;
$a['d'] = 4;

$endkey= end(array_keys($a));

foreach( $a as $q => $x )
{

  # Some operations ....

  if( $endkey == $q  ){ 
     #Want to do some more operation
     echo 'last key = '.$q.' and value ='.$x;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should check the key, not value, since the value is not necessarily unique.