# Getting rid of the last comma from the php foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I'm retrieving this value from single block of the table i.e,

sample1,sample2,sample3,

I dont want the last comma to be retrieved as my output is creating an empty result at the end. Here's my code:

```
$imageExtractExplode = explode(",", $imageExtract);
foreach
($imageExtractExplode as $imageExtractFinal){
//my echo code
}
```

How do i stop the last comma from getting displayed

Comment: You can use a regex? something like `/(.*?),$/$1` should do the trick

Comment: A regex? Why not just use `trim($imageExtract,",")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this, You can use `rtrim` function to remove last comma and explode the removed string.

```
   $imageExtract = rtrim("sample1,sample2,sample3,", ",");
   $imageExtractExplode = explode(",", $imageExtract);

  foreach($imageExtractExplode as $imageExtractFinal){
     //my echo code
  }
```

OR `substr($string, 0, -1);`

```
   $imageExtract = substr("sample1,sample2,sample3,", 0, -1);
   $imageExtractExplode = explode(",", $imageExtract);

  foreach($imageExtractExplode as $imageExtractFinal){
     //my echo code
  }
```

Comment: The problem with the substr() as you present it is that it assumes there is always a comma at the end of those strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use preg_split() instead of explode() as it gives you a way to ignore empty strings:

```
$imageExtractExplode = preg_split("/,/", $imageExtract, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

That way you also avoid empty string problems if there are two commas in a row.

See details here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$imageExtractExplode = explode(",", $imageExtract);
array_pop($imageExtractExplode); // THIS .. ! 
foreach($imageExtractExplode as $imageExtractFinal){
   //my echo code
}
```

Comment: If he always have a comma at the end, it will work, but if the string does not always have an ending comma, I'm not too sure that's a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $imageExtract = rtrim($imageExtract,',');
    $imageExtractExplode = explode(",", $imageExtract);
    foreach ($imageExtractExplode as $imageExtractFinal){
       //my echo code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an earlier version of PHP? I don't seem to have that problem but I'm running 5.3.

```
// Explode the values
$imageExtractExplode = explode(",", $imageExtract);
// Run foreach loop
foreach ($imageExtractExplode as $imageExtractFinal) {
  // Check to see if the value is empty or not. If it is empty, skip it.
  if (!empty($imageExtractFinal)) {
    //my echo code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substr](http://www.php.net/substr) to extract part of the string.

```
$str = "sample1,sample2,sample3,";    
$rs = substr($str, 0, -1);  // returns "sample1,sample2,sample3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [reset](http://www.php.net/reset) and [end](http://www.php.net/end) to generate a custom `last()` function - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8780881/66482) from [Rok Kralj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924109/rok-kralj) for details.

```
function last($array, $key) {
    end($array);
    return $key === key($array);
}

foreach($array as $key => $element) {
    if (last($array, $key))
        echo 'LAST ELEMENT!';
}
```