# How to change class of first echo result in PHP?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, class, echo

Easy one, but I can't find an answer.

I wanna to list sub-categories to create tabs in code below. This one works fine in my output. But the first tab needs a `<li class= "selected" >` to show the content on page load .

How to force the first echo result to include a class on `<li>` element ?

.

.

.

[ Output ]

Actual: .......... Category 1 | Category 2 | Category 3

Needed: .......... Category 1* | Category 2 | Category 3

*class="selected"

```
  <ul class="cd-tabs-navigation">

  <?php
  $argumentos = array(
  'hide_empty' => 1,
  'child_of' => 44,
  );
  $categories = get_categories($argumentos);
  foreach($categories as $category) {
  echo '<li><a data-content="' . $category->slug . '" href="#' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
  }
  ?>

  </ul>
```

.

.

[ EDIT ]

The solution by Lal. Thank you everyone!

```
  foreach($categories as $category) {
  if(++$i==1)
  echo '<li class="selected"><a class="selected" data-content="' . $category->slug . '" href="#' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
  else
  echo '<li><a data-content="' . $category->slug . '" href="#' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
  }
```

Comment: why do you want the class to be added? is it for applying styles?

Comment: I need the class to active one script. I'm using this code system.

http://codyhouse.co/gem/responsive-tabbed-navigation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a counter.. Not sure if this is the right way to do it..

Change your `foreach` as follows

```
$i=0;
foreach($categories as $category) {
  if($i==0)
    echo '<li class="selected"><a data-content="' . $category->slug . '" href="#' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
  else
    echo '<li><a data-content="' . $category->slug . '" href="#' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
  $i++;
  }
```

**OR**

As suggested in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244/how-to-determine-the-first-and-last-iteration-in-a-foreach-loop), you could **use `array_shift()` to process the first item in the array separatley**.

That is, do it as below

```
$first = array_shift($categories);
echo '<li class="selected"><a data-content="' . $first ->slug . '" href="#' . $first ->slug . '">' . $first ->name . '</a></li>';
foreach($categories as $category) {
  echo '<li><a data-content="' . $category->slug . '" href="#' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
}
```

Read more about `array_shift()` in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: Almost! I just need the value (++$i == 1) instead 0 to work! I included the final code in question.

Simple and clean. Thank you very much, pal!

Comment: @Lal You're not incrementing `$i` in your first example, so `$i == 0` will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

Lal's solution will work fine (as long as you increment `$i`), but here's a simpler way to do it without an extra variable for the counter :

```
foreach($categories as $index => $category){
   if(!$index) echo "This is the first element";
   else echo "This is not the first element";
}
```

(not sure if this should be an edit or an answer since it's basically the same method but with a slightly simpler synthax, I'll post as an answer for now)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax for foreach. Using this syntax you have in $k the index of the iteration, while in $v the value of the array you're iterating. So if $k == 0 you're in the first iteration.

```
$a = array("first", "second", "third", "fourth");

foreach ($a as $k=>$v) {
    echo $k . "--->" . $v ;
    if($k == 0){
        echo "First iteration!";
        //Do your stuff 
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: He is doing just that

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Why does it not answer? If he uses this syntax he can make a check on $key variable. If it's 0 he's in the first iteration, so he can add a class to the html.

Comment: So say that in your answer otherwise your answer means nothing