# Removing the last trailing separator in foreach in php

Tags: php

Am having a foreach loop using php and separating the next item with / i would like the / to be removed in the last item

This is the code:

```
<?php
            $contacts = TblContact::find()->orderBy("id")->all();
            foreach ($contacts as $contact){
                echo $contact->contact."/";   //...  this has the separator /
            }
            ?>
```

currently it generates:

```
2362/2332/3332/
```

I would like it to generate

```
2362/2332/3332    ... this has no trailing /
```

Comment: you can use a condition in your foreach loop to get the last index (and so remove the last "/" : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1070256/6028607

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $contacts = TblContact::find()->orderBy("id")->all();
    $contactList = [];
     foreach ($contacts as $contact){
        $contactList[] = $contact->contact;
     }
    echo implode("/", $contactList)
?>
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

You can use pluck and implode:

```
$contacts = TblContact::find()->orderBy("id")->pluck('contact')->all();

echo implode('/', $contacts);
```