# PHP / Remove symbol from echo after final foreach iteration

Tags: php, foreach, echo, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator.

How can I make that after the final iteration of the foreach loop the `plus` symbol in the `echo` command disappears?
Now it's being displayed as

> 55 + 22 + 4 **+** = RESULT

```
$numbers = array (55, 22 , 4);
        foreach ($numbers as $number) {
            echo "$number + ";
```

Comment: Probably, you don't want to echo directly? Removing outputted characters is not possible, or at least not worth the overhead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function instead of foreach:

```
echo implode(" + ", $numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need foreach

```
$numbers = array (55, 22 , 4);
$i=0;
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $i++;
    echo "$number ";
    if(count($numbers) != $i){
        echo "+ ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070256/6600883), it has a great answer. For your use case I would suggest the same as Tomasz. But in case you want to know how you can find the last loop I'll leave this here.

```
$numbers = array(55, 22, 4);
$i = 0;
$len = count($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        // first
    } else if ($i == $len - 1) {
        // last
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another easy way for that, you don't need to use loops here.
Try it with the `implode()` method.

```
$numbers = array (55, 22 , 4);
echo implode(' + ', $numbers);
```