# identifying column number in PHP mysqli_fetch_row() WHILE loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to identify whether I am looking at the first column in the array.

I haven't tried anything, but googled plenty and cannot find a solution.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) {
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach ($row as $col) {
        if () //NEED CODE HERE
        echo "<td><a href = 'https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup' target = '_blank'>$col</a></td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: I suggest looking at `$row`, to see how you would be able to get the values of each column per row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the first and last iteration in a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244/how-to-determine-the-first-and-last-iteration-in-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysqli_fetch_row](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) fetches "one row of data from the result set and returns it as an enumerated array, where each column is stored in an array offset starting from 0 (zero)." So the key of the column is the same as column order.

So you can do this:

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) {
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach ($row as $key => $col) {
        if ($key === 0) {
          echo "<td><a href = 'https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup' target = '_blank'>$col</a></td>";
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

But column is subjected to changes in database structure and SQL query changes. I would personally prefer [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) or [mysqli_fetch_object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) so I can use the column by name instead of order number. Its less error prone. For example,

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach ($row as $key => $col) {
        if ($key === 'ip_address') {
          echo "<td><a href = 'https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup' target = '_blank'>$col</a></td>";
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Note: `$sql` here should be a `mysqli_query` result instead of the actual SQL string.

Comment: thanks.  I went with the first code sample you gave me.  works fine.