# Separate categories with comma

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

Very new to Wordpress and web design. I have this function for separating categories with a comma ",". But it also adds the comma after the last category. Making it look like this:

Category1, Category2, Category3,

When I want it like this:

Category1, Category2, Category3

Without the last comma behind Category3

How can I stop the function from adding the last comma?

```
<?php
    $category_detail = get_the_category($post->ID); //$post->ID
    foreach ($category_detail as $cd) {
        echo $cd->cat_name . ', ';
    }
    ?>
```

Regards

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244/how-to-determine-the-first-and-last-iteration-in-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Just use `implode()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the first and last iteration in a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244/how-to-determine-the-first-and-last-iteration-in-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 1):

There is many approaches to splitting arrays values.

Indeed you could achieve it via a `foreach` loop, by counting iterations.

```
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$i = 0;
foreach ($categories as $category) {
  $i++;
  echo $category->cat_name;
  if ($i < count($items))
    echo ', ';
};
```

Tho a more concise approach would be using the [`implode()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp) native function:

```
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
echo implode(', ', $categories);
```

Comment: The second approach isn't correct. This returns an error as `$categories` is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

With this foreach loop you are actually converting an array into string. Thus, if it is more understandable to use, you could just erase the last char like this:

```
<?php
    $str=''; //single quotes
    $category_detail = get_the_category($post->ID); //$post->ID
    foreach ($category_detail as $cd) {
        $str .= $cd->cat_name . ', ';
    }
echo substr($str, 0, -1);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was being lazy, and searching Google for this, but none of these were quite what I was searching for. I wrote this and will leave it here for anyone else on a similar search.

Add this to your functions.php:

```php
function comma_separated_blog_categories( $id, $class = '' )
{
    // Get the category object
    $categories = get_the_category( $id );
    // Bail if nothing is found
    if ( is_null( $categories ) )
    {
        return;
    }
    // Create an empty array for the output
    $output = array();
    // Loop over the categories
    foreach ( $categories as $category )
    {
        // Category is an object, so grab the name and the id
        $name     = $category->name;
        $url      = get_category_link( $category->ID );
        // Create the output and include our data
        $output[] = '<a href="' . $url . '" class="' . $class . '">' . $name . '</a>';
    }
    // Finally implode the output to apply the comma if it's required...
    return implode( ',', $output );
}
```

Then in your templates, echo the function and pass in the post_id and a *class (optional)

```php
<?php echo comma_separated_blog_categories(get_the_ID(), 'category-item'); ?>
```