# PHP Foreach If Array Last

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

```
foreach( $tabs2 as $tab2 => $name ){
    $class = ( $tab2 == $current ) ? ' current' : '';
    echo("<li class='posts'><a href='?page=pigg&tab=help&tab2=$tab2' class='$class'>$name");
    echo(' |'); // If array last then do not display
    echo('</a></li>');
}
```

I'm using a foreach loop to create a navigation for a WordPress plugin I'm working on, but I don't want the ' |' to be displayed for the last element, the code above is what I've got so far, I was thinking of using an if statement on the commented line, but not sure what the best approach would be, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can move the 2nd and 3rd echo above the first one. Then if (iteration== first_time) "do_not_echo_2nd,3rd".

Comment: Take a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29474468/1478566

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The [`end()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function is what you need:

```
if(end($tabs2) !== $name){
    echo ' |'; // not the last element
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, I'll accept this as the answer, but I got to wait 3 minutes. xD

Comment: @KristianMatthews, you nearly waited 2 years now btw. :)

Comment: Minor tweak, I would cache end($tabs2) in a var before the foreach loop so that the end function isn't run every time.

Comment: What if we got two equal values in the array, 1 in the end and the other in the middle? Wouldn't this be quite  misleading..

Comment: @mikewasmike you could always change the if to be if((end($tab2) !== $tab2) && (end($name) !== $name)). This would only ever trigger the second value if the first is true, which isn't too bad.

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to check for first, rather than last. So I'd do it this way instead.

```
$first = true;
foreach( $tabs2 as $tab2 => $name ){
    if ($first) {
      $first = false;
    } else {
      echo(' | ');
    }
    $class = ( $tab2 == $current ) ? ' current' : '';
    echo("<li class='posts'><a href='?page=pigg&tab=help&tab2=$tab2' class='$class'>$name</a></li>");
}
```

I also combined the last two `echos` together.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this just immediately sets `$first = true;` then `$first = false;` essentially.

Comment: Hm, that's surprising -- it doesn't only echo out the break at the beginning of each non-first line?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to find out what is the **last key of the array**, and doing so by finding the array length, using the **count()** function.
Afterwords we gonna create a counter and add +1 on every loop. 
If the counter and the last key are equal then it is the last key.

```
    $last = count($array);
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($array as $key => $val){
    if ($counter != $last){
        // all keys but the last one
        // do something     
       $counter++; // add one to counter count
        }
        else {
            // this is for the last key
    }// end else

}// end foreach
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this way:

```
$arrLi = array();
foreach( $tabs2 as $tab2 => $name ){
  $class = ( $tab2 == $current ) ? ' current' : '';
  $arrLi[] = "<li class='posts'><a href='?page=pigg&tab=help&tab2=$tab2' class='$class'>$name</a></li>";
}
echo implode('|', $arrLi);
```

Answer (score 1):

end() is good function to use

```
foreach( $tabs2 as $tab2 => $name ){
if(end($tabs2)== $name)
 echo "|";
}
```

or you can do it manually for more understanding

```
  $copyofarry = $tabs2;
    $last = array_pop($copyofarry);
    foreach( $tabs2 as $tab2 => $name ){
        if($last == $name)
         echo "|";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is possible:

```
$size = count($tabs2);
$counter = 0;
foreach( $tabs2 as $tab2 => $name ){
    $class = ( $tab2 == $current ) ? ' current' : '';
    echo("<li class='posts'><a href='?page=pigg&tab=help&tab2=$tab2' class='$class'>$name");
    if ( ++$counter < $size ){
        echo(' |'); // If array last then do not display     
    }
    echo('</a></li>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pop the last element first? So you do not need to check if the current element is the last element in each iteration.

The function array_pop(&$array) returns the last element and removes it from the array.

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
    <?php 
        $lastBreadcrumb = array_pop($breadcrumb);
        foreach ($breadcrumb as $crumb){ ?>
            <a href=""><?php echo $crumb; ?></a>
        <?php } ?><span><?php echo $lastBreadcrumb?></span>
</div>
```