# Foreach loop with extra filter -> need to identify last entry

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to get the last entry in a foreach loop but struggling so far. My biggest problem is that once inside the foreach loop, I need to filter the array by eliminating every author who has 0 posts. This is my code so far:

```
$authors = get_users('orderby=nicename');


foreach ($authors as $author ) {
      if ( count_user_posts( $author->id ) >= 1 ) { IF LAST {special <li>} else {normal <li> }
```

Can anyone shed some light on how to get the last entry in this scenario? Thanks

Comment: [Find the last element of an array while using a foreach loop in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665135/find-the-last-element-of-an-array-while-using-a-foreach-loop-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write a function to filter the array and then you can pop the last item off of it like this:

```
// use this section of code in PHP >= 5.3 - utilizes anonymous function
$filtered_array = array_filter($authors, function($author) {
    if(count_user_posts($author->id) >= 1) return true;
    return false;
});

// use this section of code for older versions of PHP - uses regular function
function author_filter($author) {
    if(count_user_posts($author->id) >= 1) return true;
    return false;
}
$filtered_array = array_filter($authors, 'author_filter');

// the rest is the same regardless of PHP version
$last_author = array_pop($filtered_array);

// output
foreach($filtered_array as $author) {
    // regular output
}
// then do special output for $last_author
```

Comment: I think this is the way to do it, although I haven't quite managed to make it work with your code yet! Thanks

Comment: @user1945912 What problem are you having? Note I just realized that I left off the `s` on `$authors` for the first parameter passed to `array_filter`.  Maybe this was a problem for you.

Comment: @user1945912 Note I just realized that I left off the `s` on `$authors` for the first parameter passed to `array_filter`.  Maybe this was a problem for you. Also are you using PHP 5.3 or greater?  If not you will not be able to use the anonymous function as a callback to `array_filter` as I have done.  Instead, the callback function would need to be defined separately and then named in the `array_filter` call.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$numItems = count($arr);
echo "<ul>";
for($i = 0; $i < $numItems; $i++) {
    if(as_zero_post){
        //$i++;
        continue;       
    }
    $i == $numItems-1 ? "<li class='last-item'>".$arr[$i]."</li>" : "<li class='normal-item'>".$arr[$i]."</li>";

} 
echo "</ul>"

?>
```