# Add a blank line at end of a array in php

Tags: php

I would like to add a blank line at end of the last `$member` in below code to differentiate between each group. I have tried with below code

```
foreach($members as $key => $member)
{
    $member = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $member));
    $dev = " $member part of Form; <br>";
    echo str_replace("<br>", "\r\n", $dev);

    if($key == count($member)-0) 
    {
        $space = "<br>";
        echo str_replace("<br>", "\r\n", $space);
    }
}
```

But It adding a blank space after each 2 line. How can I add space only at end of the last string ?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($members as $key => $member)
{

$member = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $member));
$dev = " $member part of Form; <br>";
echo str_replace("<br>", "\r\n", $dev);
if($key == count($members)-1) <!--- ** check this line ---->
{
$space = "<br>";
echo str_replace("<br>", "\r\n", $space);
}

}
```

** You have counted the value of the key ($member) but actually it will be count of the original array ($members). Here $key starts from zero and it will end previous number of total array count.

I don't know your array structure of $members. You may use bellow code

```
$count = count($members);
$i  = 1;
foreach($members as $key => $member)
{

$member = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $member));
$dev = " $member part of Form; <br>";
echo str_replace("<br>", "\r\n", $dev);
if($i == $count) 
{
$space = "<br>";
echo str_replace("<br>", "\r\n", $space);
}
$i ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. If you want to add a newline after the last item, you can do so after the loop:

```
foreach ($members as $key => $member) {
    # ...
}
echo "\r\n";
```

If you need it inside the loop, you will need to test for the last key. One way of doing this is by manipulating the [array's internal pointer](http://php.net/function.end.php):

```
# Set internal pointer of array to the last entry:
end($members)
# Get the key of that last entry:
$lastKey = key($members)
foreach ($members as $key => $member) {
    # ...
    if ($key === $lastKey) {
        echo "\r\n";
    }
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a newline "at the end of the last string", just echo it after the loop. But use the constant PHP_EOL instead of "\r\n".

Concatenating PHP_EOL to the end of *each* line will give you output that displays more or less the same in a browser and at the command line. Echoing one more PHP_EOL after the loop will insert a blank line that's visible from the command line, but not from the browser. If you need a blank line (more whitespace) in the browser, use CSS instead.

Since you seem to know how to replace `<br>` tags already, I ignored that part of your code. If you really need to *replace* those tags instead of just making your text more readable from the command line, you can easily do that.

```
$ cat code/php/test.php
<?php
$members = array(0 => 'Member0', 1 => 'Member1', 2 => 'Member2', 3 => 'Member3');
foreach($members as $key => $member)
{
    $member = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $member));
    echo " $member part of Form; <br>".PHP_EOL;
}
echo PHP_EOL;
?>
$ php code/php/test.php
 Member0 part of Form; <br>
 Member1 part of Form; <br>
 Member2 part of Form; <br>
 Member3 part of Form; <br>

$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$numItems = count($members);
$i = 0;
foreach($members as $key=>$member) {
  if(++$i === $numItems) {
    $space = "<br">;
    echo str_replace("<br>", "\r\n", $space);
  }
}
```

[Find the last element of an array while using a foreach loop in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665135/find-the-last-element-of-an-array-while-using-a-foreach-loop-in-php)