# PHP - effective way to determine last loop in foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Whenever I have to determine if currect loop in foreach cycle is the last one, i use something like this:

```
<?php
$i = count($myArray);
foreach ($myArray as $item) {
    /** code goes here... */
    $i--;
    if ($i == 0) {
        /** something happens here */
    }
}
?>
```

Typically this could by done very easily in templating systems (such as Latte, Smarty, etc...) by knowing the cycle variables (first, last,...). And my question: Is there a similar functionality in PHP?

The key is that you have to create the `$i` variable, then increase it and check the value. I just want to know if there exists a simpler solution to make my life a little bit easier. :)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665135/find-the-last-element-of-an-array-while-using-a-foreach-loop-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244/how-to-determine-the-first-and-last-iteration-in-a-foreach-loop

Comment: I checked and they're using the solution with $i variable or the (generally) wrong solution with `end()` function - as @nospor mentioned.

Answer (score 10):

Use this within your `foreach` for checking if the item is the last item.

```
if ($item === end($myArray)) {
    // Last item
}
```

For checking if the item is the first item

```
if ($item === reset($myArray)) {
    // First item
}
```

Comment: So look at this example: array with values: 2,4,5,2 - your code will return true for first element because first and last has the same value

Comment: Ah yes, true. If the array is known to have non-unique values, this will work.

Comment: Worked, thanks phreakv6 :D

Answer (score 0):

You find the last item by checking if ($item === end($myArray)) {}

```
foreach($myArray as $key => $item) {
   echo $item."<br />";
   end($myArray);
   if ($key === key($myArray)) {
      echo 'LAST ELEMENT!';
   }
}
```

Comment: $myArray = array("aa","bb","cc","dd"); - define array like this

Comment: This code also is not properly, eg for arrays: [1,0,false,2,3,4]

Comment: Fixing to end is also not wright for arrays: [1,2,3,4,1]

Comment: And you have also PARSE ERROR now because you forgot about {

Comment: @RiggsFolly it will be wrong for every array which contains duplicated data with last element

Comment: `end($myArray);` and `key($myArray);` should be before loop. There is no point to check it every time in loop