# Get last two items of json_decode results with PHP

Tags: php, json

The following code works and pulls all the images in from the json file.

```
    $content = file_get_contents('URL');
    $json = json_decode($content, true);

    foreach($json['format'] as $item) {
            echo '<img src="' . $item['picture'] . '">';
    }
```

Is there a way that I can have it only grab the last two pictures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the last element of an array while using a foreach loop in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665135/find-the-last-element-of-an-array-while-using-a-foreach-loop-in-php)

Comment: `array_pop`, `array_pop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

```
$result = array_slice($json['format'], -2);
```

Have a try.

Comment: Based on the code in my original post, where would I put that line?

Comment: Right before the foreach loop and then `foreach ($result as $item) { ... }`.

Comment: Don 't forget to mark this answer as the right one.

Comment: I did but I don't have enough reputation points for it to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$numItems = count(foreach($json['format']);
$i = 0;
foreach($json['format'] as $item) {
  if(++$i === $numItems-1) {
    result1 = $json['format'][$i]
    echo "first picture!";
  } if(++$i === $numItems) {
    result2 = $json['format'][$i]
    echo "second picture!";
  }
}
```

And result1 and result2 is your pictures

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the order of the array, run it backwards in your foreach loop, grab the first two then break.

```
$reversed = array_reverse($json);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($reversed['format'] as $item) {
    if ($counter == 2) {
          break;
     }
     //your echo image code
++$counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My version using [`array_pop`](http://php.net/array_pop):

```
$content = file_get_contents('URL');
$json = json_decode($content, true); 

// take last element of array, array reduces by 1 element
$last = array_pop($json['format']);
print_r($last);

// take last element of array again, array reduces by 1 element
$last = array_pop($json['format']);
print_r($last);

// Beware - using `$json['format']` later means that 
// you use array without two last elements
```