# How to get last items first by using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, foreach

I use foreach to show items from mysql table, but it lists first items first. 
I want to list last items first.
**The code:**

```
foreach ( $result as $print )   { 
 $print->sender_user;
 $print->reciever_user;
 $print->content;
}
```

> I mean that if I add a new item to mysql table this code should show
>   it above the other items.
>   But it shows first added item last.

Comment: only last item or Whole loop In reverse ?

Comment: Then you can get it from query itself by simply adding `DESC` in your select query

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY` keyword.

Comment: use a array_reverse($result), if want to reverse whole object

Comment: Just reverse your array :

    $arr = array_reverse($print);

Comment: if there are two items in table and their names "a" and "b". And last added item is "a" item, I want to show first "a" item and then show "b" item. but this code shows "b" item first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the last element of an array while using a foreach loop in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665135/find-the-last-element-of-an-array-while-using-a-foreach-loop-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, use `array_reverse`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

> array_reverse — Return an array with elements in reverse order

```
$result = array_reverse($result);

foreach ( $result as $print )   { 
     $print->sender_user;
     $print->reciever_user;
     $print->content;
}
```

Otherwise if it's numerically indexed you can always use `for`

```
$len = count($result)-1;

for($i=$len; $i>=0; --$i){
   $row = $result[$i];
}
```

And my favorite

```
$result = [1,2,3,4];

$row = end($result);
do{
   echo $row."\n";
}while($row = prev($result));
```

Try it here

https://3v4l.org/NINss

And with just `while`, you cant do `prev` in the while condition because you lose the last element of the array, so it's a bit lamer.

```
$result = [1,2,3,4];

$row = end($result);
while($row = current($result)){
    echo $row."\n";

    prev($result);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/No1Rb

I think that is about it, I could probably do one with `goto` but that would be showing off.

Comment: Sure I put a few other variations in there, the `do{..}while();` is my favorite.