# The simplest way to comma-delimit a list?

Tags: java, pretty-print

What is the clearest way to comma-delimit a list in Java?

I know several ways of doing it, but I'm wondering what the best way is (where "best" means clearest and/or shortest, not the most efficient.

I have a list and I want to loop over it, printing each value.  I want to print a comma between each item, but not after the last one (nor before the first one).

```
List --> Item ( , Item ) *
List --> ( Item , ) * Item
```

Sample solution 1:

```
boolean isFirst = true;
for (Item i : list) {
  if (isFirst) {
    System.out.print(i);        // no comma
    isFirst = false;
  } else {
    System.out.print(", "+i);   // comma
  }
}
```

Sample solution 2 - create a sublist:

```
if (list.size()>0) {
  System.out.print(list.get(0));   // no comma
  List theRest = list.subList(1, list.size());
  for (Item i : theRest) {
    System.out.print(", "+i);   // comma
  }
}
```

Sample solution 3:

```
  Iterator<Item> i = list.iterator();
  if (i.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(i.next());
    while (i.hasNext())
      System.out.print(", "+i.next());
  }
```

These treat the first item specially; one could instead treat the last one specially.

Incidentally, here is how `List` `toString` *is* implemented (it's inherited from `AbstractCollection`), in Java 1.6:

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> i = iterator();
    if (! i.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = i.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! i.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```

It exits the loop early to avoid the comma after the last item.  BTW: this is the first time I recall seeing "(this Collection)"; here's code to provoke it:

```
List l = new LinkedList();
l.add(l);
System.out.println(l);
```

I welcome any solution, even if they use unexpected libraries (regexp?); and also solutions in languages other than Java (e.g. I think Python/Ruby have an *intersperse* function - how is *that* implemented?).

*Clarification*: by libraries, I mean the standard Java libraries.  For other libraries, I consider them with other languages, and interested to know how they're implemented.

*EDIT* toolkit mentioned a similar question: [Last iteration of enhanced for loop in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285523/last-iteration-of-for-loop-in-java)

And another:
[Does the last element in a loop deserve a separate treatment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156650/does-the-last-element-in-a-loop-deserve-a-separate-treatment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to build a string of delimited items in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java)

Answer (score 245, accepted):

## Java 8 and later

Using [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class, and [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) method :

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
list.forEach(item -> joiner.add(item.toString());
return joiner.toString();
```

Using [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), and [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html):

```
return list.stream().
       map(Object::toString).
       collect(Collectors.joining(",")).toString();
```

## Java 7 and earlier

See also [#285523](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285523/last-iteration-of-for-loop-in-java/285628#285628)

```
String delim = "";
for (Item i : list) {
    sb.append(delim).append(i);
    delim = ",";
}
```

Comment: A very surprising way to store state!  It's almost OO polymorphic.  I don't like the unnecessary assignment every loop, but I bet it's more efficient than an if. Most solutions repeat a test we know won't be true - though inefficient, they're probably the clearest.

Thanks for the link!

Comment: I like this, but because it's clever and surprising, I thought it wouldn't be appropriate to use (surprising is not good!).  However, I couldn't help myself.  I'm still not sure about it; however, it is so short that it is easy to work out provided there's a comment to tip you off.

Comment: @13ren: You and Uncle Bob need to have a talk about code that is "clever and surprising."

Comment: I feel like I wasted years not knowing this^^;

Comment: Why Java needs to turn such task into an ugly code?

Comment: @eduardo - I know. Clojure has a much simpler syntax: `(clojure.string/join "," my list)`

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to StringJoiner..love it

Answer (score 84):

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(list,",");
```

Comment: Found the source: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/java/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java?view=markup
The join method has 9 overloadings.  The iteration-based ones are like "Sample solution 3"; the index-based ones use: if (i > startIndex) { <add separator> }

Comment: I'm really after implementations though.  It's a good idea to wrap it up in a function, but in practice, my delimiter is sometimes a newline, and each line is also indented to some specified depth.  Unless... join(list, "\n"+indent)  ...will that always work?  Sorry, just thinking aloud.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the prettiest and shortest solution

Comment: probably, list.iterator()?

Answer (score 35):

Java 8 provides several new ways to do this:

- The [`join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method on `String`.
- A [`joining`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--) collector for streams from the `Collectors` class.
- The [`StringJoiner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class.

Example:

```
// Util method for strings and other char sequences
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
String listStr1 = String.join(",", strs);

// For any type using streams and collectors
List<Object> objs = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
String listStr2 = objs.stream()
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(joining(",", "[", "]"));

// Using the new StringJoiner class
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ", "[", "]");
joiner.setEmptyValue("<empty>");
for (Integer i : objs) {
  joiner.add(i.toString());
}
String listStr3 = joiner.toString();
```

The approach using streams assumes `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;`.

Comment: This is IMHO, if you are using java 8, the best answer.

Answer (score 19):

```
Joiner.on(",").join(myList)
```

[Joiner](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html).

Comment: I came here looking for something that does exactly this. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 7):

If you use the Spring Framework you can do it with [StringUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html):

```
public static String arrayToDelimitedString(Object[] arr)
public static String arrayToDelimitedString(Object[] arr, String delim)
public static String collectionToCommaDelimitedString(Collection coll)
public static String collectionToCommaDelimitedString(Collection coll, String delim)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how is it implemented?

Answer (score 6):

Based on Java's List toString implementation:

```
Iterator i = list.iterator();
for (;;) {
  sb.append(i.next());
  if (! i.hasNext()) break;
  ab.append(", ");
}
```

It uses a grammar like this:

```
List --> (Item , )* Item
```

By being last-based instead of first-based, it can check for skip-comma with the same test to check for end-of-list.   I think this one is very elegant, but I'm not sure about clarity.

Answer (score 6):

There is a pretty way to achieve this using Java 8:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
String joinedString = String.join(",", list);
```

Comment: TextUtils.join(",", list);

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i=0, length=list.size(); i<length; i++)
  result+=(i==0?"":", ") + list.get(i);
```

Comment: Yes it's a bit cryptic, but an alternative to what's already been posted.

Comment: I think the code looks fine, IMHO its more pretty than your other answer and its hardly 'cryptic'. Wrap it up in a method called Join and your laughing, still I would expect the language to have a better way of solving what is really a common problem.

Comment: @tarn: you think it looks good because you have a Python/perl background ;) I like it as well

Answer (score 4):

```
String delimiter = ",";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Item i : list) {
    sb.append(delimiter).append(i);
}
sb.toString().replaceFirst(delimiter, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

One option for the foreach loop is:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String s:list){
  if (sb.length()>0) sb.append(",");
  sb.append(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
for(Iterator it=list.iterator; it.hasNext(); ) {
  if (result.length()>0)
    result.append(", ");
  result.append(it.next());
}
```

**Update**: As Dave Webb mentioned in the comments this may not produce correct results if the first items in the list are empty strings.

Comment: meh.. still has the if in the loop.

Comment: You can use a foreach loop to make it shorter.

Comment: That won't work if the first item in the list is an empty string.

Comment: @Dave Webb: Yes, thanks. The question does not have such a requirement though.

Comment: @cherovium: The question doesn't say the none of the items will be the empty string so it's an implicit requirement.  If you're creating a CSV file empty fields can be pretty common.

Comment: Turns out Jon Skeet gave this answer, too (meaning you're in good company): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285523/last-iteration-of-for-loop-in-java/285544#285544

Comment: For heavens sake, use a StringBuilder

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this :

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Iterator it = myList.iterator();
if (it.hasNext()) { sb.append(it.next().toString()); }
while (it.hasNext()) { sb.append(",").append(it.next().toString()); }
```

Though I think I'll to a this check from now on as per the Java implementation ;)

Comment: That's same logic as Sample 3,  I like it because it does nothing unnecessary. However, I don't know if it is the clearest.  BTW: it's slightly more efficient if you put the while inside the if, by avoiding two tests when the list is empty.  It also makes it slighly clearer, to me.

Comment: For heavens sake, use a StringBuilder

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Groovy (which runs on the JVM):

```
def list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
println list.join(',')
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm interested in implementations.  How is this one implemented?

Answer (score 2):

(Copy paste of my own answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285523/last-iteration-of-for-loop-in-java/669806#669806).) Many of the solutions described here are a bit over the top, IMHO, especially those that rely on external libraries. There is a nice clean, clear idiom for achieving a comma separated list that I have always used. It relies on the conditional (?) operator:

**Edit**: Original solution correct, but non-optimal according to comments. Trying a second time:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0 ;  i < array.length; i++)
       builder.append(i == 0 ? "" : ",").append(array[i]);
```

There you go, in 4 lines of code including the declaration of the array and the StringBuilder.

**2nd Edit**: If you are dealing with an Iterator:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        builder.append(it.next()).append(it.hasNext() ? "," : "");
```

Comment: This and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668952/clearest-way-to-comma-delimit-a-list-java/668972#668972 above are similar.  It's short and clear, but if you only have an iterator, you'd first need to convert. Inefficient, but maybe worth it for the clarity of this approach?

Comment: Ugh, string concatenation creating a temporary StringBuilder within use of a StringBuilder.  Inefficient.  Better (more likes of Java, but better running code) would be "if (i > 0) { builder.append(','); }" followed by builder.append(array[i]);

Comment: Yes, if you look in the bytecode, you are right. I can't believe such a simple question can get so complicated. I wonder if the compiler can optimize here.

Comment: Provided 2nd, hopefully better solution.

Comment: Might be better to split them (so people can vote on one or other).

Comment: I'd assumed this test-every-time-style only worked with arrays, not iterators - good one!  BTW: You have two "hasNext()" tests - they can be combined like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668952/clearest-way-to-comma-delimit-a-list-java/669127#669127
 Shorter is nice, but which is clearer?

Comment: That is, a single hasNext() can both break out of the loop, and omit the last comma.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use something similar to version 3. It works well c/c++/bash/... :P

Answer (score 1):

This is very short, very clear, but gives my sensibilities the creeping horrors.  It's also a bit awkward to adapt to different delimiters, especially if a String (not char).

```
for (Item i : list)
  sb.append(',').append(i);
if (sb.charAt(0)==',') sb.deleteCharAt(0);
```

Inspired by: [Last iteration of enhanced for loop in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285523/last-iteration-of-for-loop-in-java/669221#669221)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't compile it... but should work (or be close to working).

```
public static <T> String toString(final List<T> list, 
                                  final String delim)
{
    final StringBuilder builder;

    builder = new StringBuilder();

    for(final T item : list)
    {
        builder.append(item);
        builder.append(delim);
    }

    // kill the last delim
    builder.setLength(builder.length() - delim.length());

    return (builder.toString());
}
```

Comment: I like this way, i would just prefer an other formatting. But to mention one small fix: If the list is empty, this will throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception. So, either do a check before the setLength, or use Math.max(0,...)

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
{ 
    if (i > 0) 
    {
        sb.append(", ");
    }

    sb.append(myList.get(i)); 
}
```

Comment: I find this one to be very easy to embed into a static utility class, while being very easy to read and understand as well. It also does't require any extra variables or state other than the list itself, the loop and the delimiter.

Comment: This will provide something like: `Item1Item2, Item3, Item4,`

Comment: For heavens sake, use a StringBuilder

Answer (score 1):

I somewhat like this approach, which I found on a blog some time ago. Unfortunately I don't remember the blog's name/URL.

You can create a utility/helper class that looks like this:

```
private class Delimiter
{
    private final String delimiter;
    private boolean first = true;

    public Delimiter(String delimiter)
    {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
            return "";
        }

        return delimiter;
    }
}
```

Using the helper class is simple as this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Delimiter delimiter = new Delimiter(", ");

for (String item : list) {
    sb.append(delimiter);
    sb.append(item);
}
```

Comment: Just a note: it should be "delimiter", not "delimeter".

Answer (score 1):

I like this solution:

```
String delim = " - ", string = "";

for (String item : myCollection)
    string += delim + item;

string = string.substring(delim.length());
```

I assume it can make use of StringBuilder too.

Answer (score 1):

Because your delimiter is ", " you could use any of the following:

```
public class StringDelim {

    public static void removeBrackets(String string) {
        System.out.println(string.substring(1, string.length() - 1));
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // Array.toString() example
        String [] arr = {"Hi" , "My", "name", "is", "br3nt"};
        String string = Arrays.toString(arr);
        removeBrackets(string);

        // List#toString() example
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Hi");
        list.add("My");
        list.add("name");
        list.add("is");
        list.add("br3nt");
        string = list.toString();
        removeBrackets(string);

        // Map#values().toString() example
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("1", "Hi");
        map.put("2", "My");
        map.put("3", "name");
        map.put("4", "is");
        map.put("5", "br3nt");
        System.out.println(map.values().toString());
        removeBrackets(string);

        // Enum#toString() example
        EnumSet<Days> set = EnumSet.allOf(Days.class);
        string = set.toString();
        removeBrackets(string);
    }

    public enum Days {
        MON("Monday"),
        TUE("Tuesday"),
        WED("Wednesday"),
        THU("Thursday"),
        FRI("Friday"),
        SAT("Saturday"),
        SUN("Sunday");

        private final String day;

        Days(String day) {this.day = day;}
        public String toString() {return this.day;}
    }
}
```

If your delimiter is ANYTHING else then this isn't going to work for you.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is the simplest to read and understand:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String string : strings) {
    sb.append(string).append(',');
}
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python its easy

",".join( yourlist )

In C# there is a static method on the String class

String.Join(",", yourlistofstrings)

Sorry, not sure about Java but thought I'd pipe up as you asked about other languages. I'm sure there would be something similar in Java.

Comment: IIRC, you get a trailing , in the .Net version. :-(

Comment: Just tested, no trailing delimiter in .NET or Python

Comment: thanks! I found the source for it: http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release22-branch/Objects/stringobject.c?view=markup  search for "Catenate everything".  It omits the separator for the last item.

Comment: @13ren Nicely done! Does it help? I had a lock and quickly remembered why I choose not to program in C these days :P

Comment: @tarn, yeah, it's an interesting example because it only adds the comman if it is not the last item:  if (i < seqlen - 1) { <add separator> }

Answer (score 0):

You can also unconditionally add the delimiter string, and after the loop remove the extra delimiter at the end.  Then an "if list is empty then return this string" at the beginning will allow you to avoid the check at the end (as you cannot remove characters from an empty list)

So the question really is:

"Given a loop and an if, what do you think is the clearest way to have these together?"

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array.length>0)          // edited in response Joachim's comment
  sb.append(array[i]);
for (int i=1; i<array.length; i++)
  sb.append(",").append(array[i]);
```

Based on [Clearest way to comma-delimit a list (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668952/clearest-way-to-comma-delimit-a-list-java/669831#669831)

Using this idea:
[Does the last element in a loop deserve a separate treatment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156650/does-the-last-element-in-a-loop-deserve-a-separate-treatment)

Comment: For this to work, you need to know that there is at least 1 element in the list, otherwise your first for-loop will crash with an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @Joachim thanks, you're right of course. What an ugly solution I wrote! I'll change `for (int i=0; i<1; i++)` to `if (array.length>0)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String join (List<String> list, String separator) {
  String listToString = "";

  if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
   return listToString;
  }

  for (String element : list) {
   listToString += element + separator;
  }

  listToString = listToString.substring(0, separator.length());

  return listToString;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to say `listToString.substring(0, listToString.length()-separator.length());`

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString(List<Item> items)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");

    for (Item item : items)
    {
        sb.append(item).append(", ");
    }

    if (sb.length() >= 2)
    {
        //looks cleaner in C# sb.Length -= 2;
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
    }

    sb.append("]");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Just noticed it's similar to the answer [TofuBeer gave](http://stackoverflow.com/q/670600/1060117)

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers uses recursion so far...

```
public class Main {

    public static String toString(List<String> list, char d) {
        int n = list.size();
        if(n==0) return "";
        return n > 1 ? Main.toString(list.subList(0, n - 1), d) + d
                  + list.get(n - 1) : list.get(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1","2","3"});
        System.out.println(Main.toString(list, ','));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String betweenComma(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    String united = "";
    for (String string : strings) {
        united = united + "," + string;
    }
    return united.replaceFirst(",", "");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### Method

```
String join(List<Object> collection, String delimiter){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int size = collection.size();
    for (Object value : collection) {
        size --;
        if(size > 0){
            stringBuilder.append(value).append(delimiter);
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

### Usage

Given the array of [1,2,3]

```
join(myArray, ",") // 1,2,3
```