# Adding commas to output

Tags: java

This is what it does:

2,

4,

6,

8,

10

I would like for it to be horizontal:
2, 4, 6, 8, 10

```
        try    { 
            PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("numbers.dat"))); 
            for(int i = start; i <= 100; i = i + 2)    { 
                fout.println(i+","); 
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearest way to comma-delimit a list (Java)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668952/clearest-way-to-comma-delimit-a-list-java)

Comment: println prints the string passed to it and then a newline character. So if you want to print all the data on the dame line, then use print rather than println which is same as println, but doesn't insert a newline character after the message.

Comment: @Logan: That worked, is there a way to remove the last comma.  It ends like this:  100,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `write()` method:

```
 for(int i = start; i <= 100; i = i + 2)    { 
    if (i > start) {
        fout.print(",");
    }

    fout.println(i); 
}
```

Then when you call `output()`, it will display as comma separated list. And for screen display

```
while((outputline = fin.readLine()) != null) { 
    System.out.print(outputline + " "); 
}
System.out.println();
```

---

Alternatively, skip saving the comma in the file and displaying will be as follows

```
int count = 0;
while((outputline = fin.readLine()) != null) { 
    if (count > 0)
        System.out.print(", ");

    System.out.print(outputline); 
    count++;
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: That added the comma, but it still is in column format and not row.  Also there isn't a comma between 2 & 4.  It goes 2 4, 6, 8, 10.

Comment: @The Gentlemen - he'll get 2 4, 6, 8, ... 100,

Comment: @Mike, I did the change, but I don't understand how you file format structure must be like.

Comment: @ The Elite Gentleman: I looked over your code, but am not sure where to input it.  I've tried several ways, but get errors.

Comment: @Mike, just substitute your loops with mine.

Answer (score 2):

Another attempt

```
for(int i = start; i <= 100; i += 2) 
    System.out.print(i + (i > 98 ? "\n" : ", "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic example of what you could do:

```
int max=11;
for(int i = 0; i < max; i += 2){
    System.out.print(i);
    if(i < max-2){
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `i = start` and if `(i < max-2)`

Comment: @MByD: For the purpose of my example `i` starts at `0`. And, since we are incrementing by `2`, I agree with your second amendment.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to do it on printing to your .dat file:

```
 for(int i = start; i <= 100; i = i + 2) { 
     fout.print(i);
     if(i < 100) {
         fout.print(", ");
     } else {
         fout.println();
     }
  }
```

If it is when printing to the system output after reading your file, try this:

```
      try    { 
        BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("numbers.dat")); 

            String outputline = ""; 
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            while((outputline = fin.readLine()) != null)    { 
            result.append(outputline).append(", "); 
            } 
            int length = result.length();
            result.delete(length - 2, length);
            System.out.println(result);
            fin.close(); 
        }
```

This uses a [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build up your result and then removes the last `,` when it is done.

Comment: Do you mean `println` or `print`?

Comment: I meant it appears the OP wants the output all on the same line, as it is in the example. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
fout.println(i + ", ");  

System.out.println(outputline + ", ");
```

This will give you commas after all the numbers but it looks like you don't need one after the final number.

You will have to remove the last comma either by using indexOf or checking for the last iteration of your loop.

Comment: You don't have a clue on the file format of `numbers.dat`, what makes you sure that your code for file reading & displaying will work?