# Most elegant way to insert delimiters into the List<String>

Tags: java, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clearest way to comma-delimit a list (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668952/clearest-way-to-comma-delimit-a-list-java)

I have a `List<String>` and I need to convert this list into the single line and insert delimiters between `String` elements of this `List`, except position before first element and after last element;

I have made a cycle like this:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (String str : list) {
    sb.append(str).append(';');
}
if(sb.length() > 0)
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
```

I don't like delete last token sentence.

So, Which is more elegant way to do same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't re-invent the wheel... the [apache commons-lang library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has the [`StringUtils.join()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.String%29) method, which does exactly what you want:

```
String s = StringUtils.join(list, ";"); // for example
```

### Java 8 update:

In java 8, the `String` class has the [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) method that does what you want:

```
String s = String.join(";", list);
```

Comment: Guava also has StringJoiner, and we are working on a similar facility for JDK8 (finally).

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at using [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) in Google's Guava Libraries.

```
String delimitedString = Joiner.on(";").join(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use, written in C# but you should be able to figure it out...

```
public static string DelimitList<T>(List<T> list, string delimiter)
{
    if (list == null || list.Count == 0 || delimiter == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    StringBuilder delimitedList = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0; index < list.Count - 1; index++)
    {
        delimitedList.Append(list[index]);
        delimitedList.Append(delimiter);
    }

    delimitedList.Append(list[list.Count - 1]);
    return delimitedList.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons Lang has a [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class with a `join` method which allows you to do that:

```
StringUtils.join(list, ";");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many recomendation and for third party libs.
My recommendation is, if you go for a `for` loop , if your code at that point does not need to be thread-safe, then use a `StringBuilder` instead. It is much faster than `StringBuffer` as it is `unsynchronized`

An example (just for different loop):

```
int len = list.size() - 1;
ListIterator<String> it = list.listIterator();  
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
while(it.hasNext() && len-- > 0){  
   sb.append(it.next()).append(";");  
}  
if(it.hasNext()){  
   sb.append(it.next());  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its not really more elegant, but you can check if its the first entry and otherwise add the delimiter upfront.

```
boolean isFirst = true;

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (String str : list) {
   if (!isFirst){
       sb.append(';');
   } 
   sb.append(str);
   isFirst = false;
}
```

Comment: Conversely, you can just do the first entry manually then use the loop to append the rest.

Comment: yes, but by just appending the delimiter every time, and deleting the last one, you're saving the "if" clause, which means the loop doesn't have a branch instruction in it, which will executed faster.

Comment: @Matt usually I wouldn't worry about the performance here. Its usually lost with IO and readabilty is more important(well this one looks nicer, but is just sligthly more readable). Checking the duplicate answer link, I do like the provided solution with adding the delimiter upfront evertime and exchanging it after the first round.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at how ArrayList.toString() is written, that may help :

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> i = iterator();
if (! i.hasNext())
    return "[]";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append('[');
for (;;) {
    E e = i.next();
    sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
    if (! i.hasNext())
    return sb.append(']').toString();
    sb.append(", ");
}
}
```

does this inspire you ?