# How to output an Array with numbers and certain formatting

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to java and am trying to output this array:
-5, -2, -12, 7, 3, 15, 10

To look exactly like this:
[ 0: -5, 1: -2, 2: 12, 3: 7, 4: 3, 5: 15, 6: 10 ]

```
public static void array(int[] numbers) {
        int index = 0;
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            System.out.print(index + ": " + numbers[i] + ", ");
            index ++;
        }
        System.out.print("]");
}
```

When I run my code it looks exactly like it should except has a comma after 10.
Any ideas on how to get rid of the last comma or a better way to do this?

Thanks for any help!
CK

Comment: For the record, your `index` and `i` are always the same value here so you don't really need them both.  If you like having the name `index` for readability, you can just use index in place of i.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearest way to comma-delimit a list (Java)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668952/clearest-way-to-comma-delimit-a-list-java)

Comment: @ChrisGuest, I don't think this is a duplicate (of that question, at least) because this question is about arrays (not lists) and the OP wants to include the indices in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add comma in print statement, when you read your last array index in the `for` loop. Here you go:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if(i == numbers.length -1) {
           System.out.print(index + ": " + numbers[i]);
        } else {
           System.out.print(index + ": " + numbers[i] + ", ");
        }
        index ++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the comma every time but the last time, you can do something like this:

```
System.out.print(index + ": " + numbers[i] + (i != numbers.length-1 ? ", " : "");
```

This will print out a comma except when on the last pass.

Also since `i` goes from zero to the limit, you don't need the `index` variable. You could just use `i` in place of `index'.

Answer (score 1):

You could put an if statement that only prints the comma if it's not the last index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    System.out.print(i + ": " + numbers[i]);
    if(i != numbers.length -1) {
       System.out.print(", ");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, print the first element before the loop and print each subsequent element with a comma before it.

```
System.out.println(0 + ": " + numbers[0]);

for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
  System.out.print(", " + index + ": " + numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: your first solution prints the comma only if _is_ the last index

Answer (score 1):

I would implement the method like this (note that `index` in your implementation is redundant because it's always equal to `i`):

```
public static void printArray(int[] numbers) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(String.format("%d: %d", i, numbers[i]));
    }
    System.out.print("[" + sb.toString() + "]");
}
```

I'm using [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which makes it easy (and effective) to compose a single `String` from the array contents. [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is useful when you want to create formatted output.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.print("[");
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    if(numbers.length -1==i)
       System.out.print(i+ ": " + numbers[i]);
     else 
       System.out.print(i + ": " + numbers[i] + ", ");          
}
System.out.print("]");
```

Answer (score 1):

With some minor changes to your code:

```
public static void array(int[] numbers) {
        //Check if the array isn't empty, you know, just in case ;)
        if (numbers.length == 0) {
            return
        }
        System.out.print("[ 0");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++){
            System.out.print(": " + numbers[i] + ", " + (i+1));
        }
        System.out.print(": " + numbers[numbers.length-1] + " ]");
}
```

Resulting in
`[ 0: -5, 1: -2, 2: 12, 3: 7, 4: 3, 5: 15, 6: 10 ]`