# How to remove the last comma from the output in java?

Tags: java

```
System.out.print(i+",");
```

I am trying to print a list of numbers using for loop and I am using the above line. But I get the output `1,2,3,`. I need `1,2,3`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The simplest way to comma-delimit a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668952/the-simplest-way-to-comma-delimit-a-list)

Comment: Could also do a conditional. `System.out.print(i < maxValue - 1 ? i + ", " : i);`

Comment: Add more Context Please. Du you use an Array? Whats the way you create i? Oder you use a list you can use an iterator und checkt the hasNext method to Stop printing the last comma

Answer (score 2):

Many ways.

1. Use a `StringBuilder` to make your string, then after the loop, if it is not empty, lop off the last character (`sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1)`).
2. Use a boolean to track if this is the first time through the loop. If yes, just print the number. If not, print a comma, then the number. Set the boolean to false after.
3. Use string joining:

```java
List<String> items = List.of("Hello", "World!");
System.out.println(String.join(", ", items));
```

Comment: Why you need to create an object (List) when String.join accepts varargs?..

Comment: Presumably he already has a list since he says "I am printing a list of numbers"... though i guess it could be an array and "list" is used in the English sense not the technical sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do... use a StringBuilder and append to it inside of the loop like this.

Once the loop is finished, your output string will be ready and you can just remove the last character (which will be the comma)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for () {
    sb.append(i+",");
}
// remove last comma
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
System.out.println(sb.toString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there's standard library's method for it:

```
String.join(", ", s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var buffer = new java.util.StringJoiner( "," );
for( var i = 1; i < endCriterion; ++i )
{
    buffer.add( Integer.toString( i );
}
System.out.println( buffer.toString() );
```

For `endCriterion == 3` this will print

```
1,2,3
```

to the console.

'java.util.StringJoiner' was added to the Java standard library with Java 8.