# Convert a list of string into a comma separated string without duplications

Tags: java, java-7

I have a list of strings in Java. I would like to to insert it into a string with commas, something like:

```
Input: [option1,option2,option3,option1,option4]
Output: option1,option2,option3,option4
```

I saw this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668952/the-simplest-way-to-comma-delimit-a-list) and I really liked this one:

```
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String delimiter= "";
        for (String i : list) {
            result.append(delimiter).append(i);
            delimiter = ",";
        }
        return result.toString();
```

But what would be the best way to add support for unique only items? How can I return a string without any duplicates? I could remove duplication from `list` first but it feels like there is a better solution here.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `Set` class?

Comment: @PM77-1 I can use everything for builtin for Java7

Comment: `list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(","))`

Comment: @Andreas Can't use stream.  OP said it had to be Java 7.

Comment: Would be nice if that restriction was mentioned *in the question*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best to avoid duplicates is to use a `Set`

- `TreeSet` for alphabetical order
- `LinkedHashSet` to keep insertion order (initial order)

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String delimiter= "";
for (String i : new LinkedHashSet<String>(list)) {
    result.append(delimiter).append(i);
    delimiter = ",";
}
return result.toString();
```

But you can just do `String.join(',', new LinkedHashSet<String>(list))`

---

Back to `List`

```
List<String> inputList = (unique) ? new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(list)) : list;
```

---

Case-insensitive

```
Set<String> check = new HashSet<String>();
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String delimiter= "";
for (String i : list) {
    if(!check.contains(i.toLowerCase())){
        result.append(delimiter).append(i);
        delimiter = ",";
        check.add(i.toLowerCase());
    }
}
return result.toString();
```

Comment: Reordering the values is probably not appropriate.

Comment: Using `HashSet` will sort alphabetically the values?

Comment: Also, I'm trying to add support to a flag. I would use something like `List<String> inputList = (unique) ? new HashSet<String>(list) : list;` But it looks like I can't convert `HashSet` to `List`. Is there a way to easily support the `unique` flag?

Comment: Using `LinkedHashSet` would retain original order (without using "external set"). Using `TreeSet` would order the values alphabetically.

Comment: @abuka123 `Collection<String> inputList = (unique ? new LinkedHashSet<>(list) : list);` --- No need to copy the values twice to get a `List`. The `for` loop works for Collections. It actually works for anything `Iterable`.

Comment: @abuka123 if you want back to list read the end of my answer, if you jsut want a Collection (no matter list or set) look ANdreas comment

Comment: Another question if you allow. Is there a way to handle case sensitive, meaning `Hi = hi` or does it making it much harder?

Comment: @abuka123 you need an external Set, as I just show in y post at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can `stream()` the list and collect only distinct values. Afterwards, you can just `String.join(...)` them to a comma separated `String`, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example values
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("option1");
    list.add("option2");
    list.add("option3");
    list.add("option4");
    list.add("option1");
    list.add("option3");
    list.add("option5");

    // stream the list and collect only distinct values in a new list
    List<String> distinctOptions = list.stream()
                                        .distinct()
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // then create a comma separated String from that list
    String commaSeparatedUniqueStrings = String.join(",", distinctOptions);
    // and print it
    System.out.println(commaSeparatedUniqueStrings);
}
```

The output is

```
option1,option2,option3,option4,option5
```

Comment: Why build a list? Why not just use the stream to build the desired result string? See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137512/convert-a-list-of-string-into-a-comma-separated-string-without-duplications#comment109897191_62137512).

Comment: @Andreas this is just an example and may of course be optimized... Sure, there's no real need for an intermediate list, but it makes the example more readable and easier to understand. But it is not optimal, I admit.

Answer (score 0):

> Extra requirements from comments:
>
> - [Limited to Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137512/convert-a-list-of-string-into-a-comma-separated-string-without-duplications#comment109897096_62137512)
> - [Support `unique` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137512/convert-a-list-of-string-into-a-comma-separated-string-without-duplications#comment109897225_62137549)
> - [Handle case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137512/convert-a-list-of-string-into-a-comma-separated-string-without-duplications#comment109897657_62137549)
> - [Optional: Alphabetical sort may be allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137512/convert-a-list-of-string-into-a-comma-separated-string-without-duplications#comment109897178_62137549)

***Sorted***

If sorting the values is ok, handling case-sensitive is easiest done using a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) with a case-insensitive [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), like the [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER), or by using a [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) for full language support.

```java
static String toString(List<String> list, boolean unique) {
    Collection<String> dataToProcess = list;
    if (unique) {
        dataToProcess = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        dataToProcess.addAll(list);
    }
    
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String delimiter= "";
    for (String s : dataToProcess) {
        result.append(delimiter).append(s);
        delimiter = ",";
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

*Test*

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("option1", "option3", "OPTION1", "OPTION2", "option4", "option2");
System.out.println(toString(list, false));
System.out.println(toString(list, true));
```

*Output*

```
option1,option3,OPTION1,OPTION2,option4,option2
option1,OPTION2,option3,option4
```

Notice how the "unique" result is sorted, but the non-unique result is not.

***Using Collator***

For better language support, use a [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html):

```java
    if (unique) {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(/*Locale.GERMANY*/);
        collator.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);
        dataToProcess = new TreeSet<>(collator);
        dataToProcess.addAll(list);
    }
```

***Unsorted***

To do it without sorting the values, we'll keep using the `TreeSet` but build a new list.

```java
    if (unique) {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(/*Locale.GERMANY*/);
        collator.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);
        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(collator);
        dataToProcess = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : list)
            if (set.add(s))
                dataToProcess.add(s);
    }
```

*Output*

```
option1,option3,OPTION1,OPTION2,option4,option2
option1,option3,OPTION2,option4
```