# How to check if end of list was reached?

Tags: python, list

If have a list, say `a=[1,2,3]`, and I want to see `if a[4] is null`, is there a way to do that, without using an exception or assertion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138873/cleanest-way-to-get-last-item-from-python-iterator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226967/last-element-in-a-python-iterator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630320/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-detect-the-last-element-in-a-python-for-loop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429098/how-to-treat-the-last-element-in-list-differently-in-python

Comment: The question is not understandable. Python does not have a concept of "null"; `a[4]` isn't "null" nor is it anything else - it **does not exist** (and keep in mind that **list indices start at 0**); and "end of list was reached" does not make any sense at all because there is no **process** described here that could "reach" elements.

Answer (score 9):

[`len`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len) will tell you the length of the list. To quote the docs:

> len(s) 
>     Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence 
>     (string, tuple or list) or a mapping (dictionary).

Of course, if you want to get the final element in a `list`, `tuple`, or `string`, since indexes are 0 based, and the length of an item is the element count, `a[len(a)-1]` will be the last item.

---

As an aside, generally, the proper way to access the last element in an object which allows numeric indexing (str, list, tuple, etc) is using `a[-1]`. Obviously, that does not involve `len` though.

Comment: an even simpler way to access the last element in a list, tuple or string: a[-1]

Answer (score 3):

with `a = [1,2,3]`  :

**a[2:3]** is **[3]**

**a[3:4]** is **[ ]**

So **a[i:i+1] != [ ]** tells if is an index of **a**

**a[i:]** does the same, but **a[i:]** creates another list, possible very long, while **a[i:i+1]** is 1 element if not empty

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach which I applied in one of the Arcade Challenges from [Code Fights](https://codefights.com/).

Basically, the end of a list is defined by:

- **list length** - *current index (iteration)* == 1

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

numbers = [1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 13, 16]

list_len = len(numbers)

for n in numbers:
    current_idx = numbers.index(n)
    print("Current Number:", numbers[current_idx])
    list_end = list_len - current_idx
    if list_end != 1:
        next_idx = current_idx + 1
        print("Next Number:   ", numbers[next_idx])
    else:
        print("End Of List!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `len`

```
if len(a) <= index:
   ...
```

Note:  Your question asks how you would find out "if `a[4]` is null".  `a[4]` isn't anything, which is why you get an `IndexError` when you try to check it.

Answer (score 2):

`a[4]` in this case will throw a `IndexError` exception, which isn't the same as comparing the value of `a` at index 4 to `None`. You can have values of `None` in a list, and if you were to compare values of `a`, then when you encounter a `None`, it doesn't mean that the index is not found in the list.  For example:

```
>>> a=[1,None,2]
>>> a[1]==None
True
>>> a[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Since lists are contiguous and indexed sequentially, the correct way to check if an index is in a list is to compare it to the `len()` of a list, but depending on the application, there are other ways around it, like catching an `IndexError`, or iteration.

```
>>> for index, value in enumerate(a):
...     print index, value
... 
0 1
1 None
2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function which behaves kind of like [dict.get()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) does for dictionaries:

```
def listget(list_, index, default=None):
    """Return the item for index if index is in the range of the list_,
    else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that
    this method never raises an IndexError."""
    if index >= len(list_) or index < -len(list_):
        return default
    else:
        return list_[index]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> names = ["Mark","Frank","James"]
>>> listget(names, 2)
'James'
>>> listget(names,-3)
'Mark'
>>> listget(names,3) # returns None
>>> listget(names,4,0)
0
```

So it will always return a value and you get no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You're not providing a specific use-case, but generally for a list your would use `len` to see how many elements are in the list.

```
if len(a) > 3:
    # Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

The general way to check if you're currently looking at the element at the end of a list (in any language) is to compare the current index you're looking at with the length of the list minus one (since indexes start at 0).

`a[4]` isn't really anything, because it doesn't exist - some languages may implement that as being null (or undefined) but many will simply throw an exception if you try to access it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the logic statement I use to check whether the end of your list has been reached:

```
arr = [1,3,2,4,5]
#counter for the array
arr_counter = 0

for ele in array:
    # check if end of list has been reached
    if (arr_counter+1) != len(arr):
        #put all your code here
        pass
    # increment the array counter
    arr_counter += 1
```

Hope this helps ! :)

Answer (score 0):

look here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-get-the-last-element-of-list/

```
test_list = [1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5] 
# printing original list  
print ("The original list is : " + str(test_list)) 
# First naive method 
# using loop method to print last element  
for i in range(0, len(test_list)): 
    if i == (len(test_list)-1): 
        print ("The last element of list using loop : "+  str(test_list[i])) 
# Second naive method         
# using reverse method to print last element 
test_list.reverse() `enter code here`
print("The last element of list using reverse : "+  str(test_list[0]))
```