# How to print a fail statement only after reaching end of loop in Python?

Tags: python, list, csv, cs50

I have a small code snippet and need help implementing a fail statement (`No match`). Here is the snippet:

```
for row in reader:
    # converts each string num --> int num
    i = 1
    while i < len(row):
        row[i] = int(row[i])
        i += 1

    if STR_count_large(sequence) == row[1:]:
        print(row[0])

    if STR_count_small(sequence) == row[1:]:
        print(row[0])
```

I iterate through each `row` in a `csv` file called `reader`, and convert each element in that row from a string to an int. After that, I compare the contents of the list of that particular row (from the 1st element to the end) against two functions that each contain a list. If the two lists match, I print `row[0]`, which simply contains the name of the person who the matching list belongs to. However, if both of these `if` statements fail after going through the `for row in reader:` loop, how would I go about printing a statement like `No match` only once? Because if I write it inside the loop, this statement would be printed `row` number of times rather than just once.

**EDIT**:
Here is my (unsuccessful) implementation using bschlueter's idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
exceptions = list()
            for row in reader:
                # converts each string num --> int num
                i = 1
                while i < len(row):
                    row[i] = int(row[i])
                    i += 1
                try:
                    if STR_count_large(sequence) == row[1:]:
                        print(row[0])
                    if STR_count_small(sequence) == row[1:]:
                        print(row[0])
                except (STR_count_large(sequence) != row[1:] and STR_count_small(sequence) != row[1:]) as exception:
                    exceptions.append(exception)
            if exceptions:
                print("No match")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accumulate errors, then check the accumulation after the completion of the loop:

```
exceptions = list()
for row in reader:
    try:
        do_a_thing(row)
    except MyException as exception:
        exceptions.append(exception)
# Do something if any exceptions were added to the list
if exceptions:
    handle_exceptions(exceptions)
```

Comment: What would be the proper way to implement this? I tried using this structure, but I do not have much familiarity with `try` and `except` in python. I've added an edit to my original post that shows my version of trying to implement this based on your suggestion.

Comment: The function `do_a_thing` needs to throw `MyException`. Exception handling in python is fairly simple, just go search for the docs. It looks like you'd be better off just using an if statement though, with a boolean value rather than the accumulator list.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more if statement with and for catching and printing no match.
add this at the end of second IF statement

```
if row == reader[len(reader)]:#Check for last iteration
    if STR_count_large(sequence) != row[1:]: and STR_count_small(sequence) != row[1:]:
        print("No Match")
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will print the `No match` statement `row` number of times (which in this case would be three times). I only want to print the `No match` statement once.

Comment: i have edited code to check for last iteraiton based on length of reader

Comment: Sorry, this also does not work because you cannot call `len()` on `reader` because it is a csv. Thank you for trying though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429260/10849457 This will help you