# Python Last Iteration in For Loop

Tags: python

Is there any simple way to find the Last Iteration of the for Loop in Python? I just want to convert a list to CSV.

Comment: No. But maybe if you explain your actual problem, we can suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: I wonder if the standard csv module might solve your problem another way.

Comment: I'm not sure why none of the replies to this question actually answer it...

Comment: Here's an actual answer for the generic situation.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1630350/804616

Comment: "Is there any simple way to find the Last Iteration of the for Loop in Python? I just want to convert a list to CSV." These are two separate questions, both of which have much better versions, so I closed this as duplicates of both. Aside from that, it is not at all clear *why knowing the "last iteration" would help" in the conversion task.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To convert a list to CSV, use the [`join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)-function:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
>>> ",".join(str(item) for item in lst)
"1,2,3,4"
```

If the list already contains only string, you just do `",".join(l)`.

Comment: this will not properly escape values containing ',' for that use the csv module

Answer (score 13):

Your best solution is probably to use the csv module, as suggested elsewhere. However, to answer your question as stated:

Option 1: count your way through using enumerate()

```
for i, value in enumerate(my_list):
    print value,
    if i < len(my_list)-1:
        print ", followed by"
```

Option 2: handle the final value (`my_list[-1]`) outside the loop

```
for value in my_list[:-1]:
    print value, ", followed by"
print my_list[-1]
```

Answer (score 12):

To convert a list to csv you could use [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

list_of_lists = ["nf", [1,2]]

with open('file', 'wb') as f:
     csv.writer(f).writerows(list_of_lists)
```

The `'file'` file would be:

```
n,f
1,2
```

Answer (score 10):

actually when a `for` loop in python ends the name that it bound is still accessible and bound to its last value:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 3:
        break
print i # prints 3
```

i use this trick with `with` like:

```
with Timer() as T:
    pass # do something
print T.format() # prints 0.34 seconds
```

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you want:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
    print(i)
else:
    print("Last i is",i)


0
1
2
3
4
Last i is 4
```

**Edited**: There is `csv` module in standard library, or simply `','.join(LIST)`

Comment: `for`'s `else` only runs if the loop exits at the end of the iterator not via `break`

Comment: I'd not come across that construction before.  Interesting.