# Printing a list separated with commas, without a trailing comma

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I am writing a piece of code that should output a list of items separated with a comma. The list is generated with a `for` loop:

```
for x in range(5):
    print(x, end=",")
```

The problem is I don't know how to get rid of the last comma that is added with the last entry in the list. It outputs this:

```
0,1,2,3,4,
```

How do I remove the ending `,`?

---

<sub>Most approaches here are based on using a single `print` call. In order to use separate calls for each `x` value, the last call would have to be handled differently. That can also be done - see [What is the pythonic way to detect the last element in a 'for' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630320/) - however, this specific problem is better tackled by using `print`-specific functionality.</sub>

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Pass `sep=","` as an argument to `print()`

You are nearly there with the print statement.

There is no need for a loop, [print](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print) has a `sep` parameter as well as `end`.

```
>>> print(*range(5), sep=", ")
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

#### A little explanation

The `print` builtin takes any number of items as arguments to be printed. Any non-keyword arguments will be printed, separated by `sep`. The default value for `sep` is a single space.

```
>>> print("hello", "world")
hello world
```

Changing `sep` has the expected result.

```
>>> print("hello", "world", sep=" cruel ")
hello cruel world
```

Each argument is stringified as with `str()`. Passing an iterable to the print statement will stringify the iterable as one argument.

```
>>> print(["hello", "world"], sep=" cruel ")
['hello', 'world']
```

However, if you put the asterisk in front of your iterable this decomposes it into separate arguments and allows for the intended use of `sep`.

```
>>> print(*["hello", "world"], sep=" cruel ")
hello cruel world

>>> print(*range(5), sep="---")
0---1---2---3---4
```

#### Using `join` as an alternative

The alternative approach for joining an iterable into a string with a given separator is to use the `join` method of a separator string.

```
>>>print(" cruel ".join(["hello", "world"]))
hello cruel world
```

This is slightly clumsier because it requires non-string elements to be explicitly converted to strings.

```
>>>print(",".join([str(i) for i in range(5)]))
0,1,2,3,4
```

#### Brute force - non-pythonic

The approach you suggest is one where a loop is used to concatenate a string adding commas along the way. Of course this produces the correct result but its much harder work.

```
>>>iterable = range(5)
>>>result = ""
>>>for i, item in enumerate(iterable):
>>>    result = result + str(item)
>>>    if i > len(iterable) - 1:
>>>        result = result + ","
>>>print(result)
0,1,2,3,4
```

Comment: You meant `*range(5)`?

Comment: Thanks for the response! The problem is that I do need a loop, the code I provided above is simplefied code. I came with a solution myself just when I posted the question. I made a string variable where I kept adding strings to with a comma and when the loop did its last run, I made an if statement to not add a comma to my variable (where I pasted all the strings to)

Comment: No problem, It may still simplify your code somewhat to generate an iterable (a list?) with your loop and then use print to render it to the console. No need for an intervening string to hold the commas.

Comment: The "loop to concatenate with an if statement" approach is very clumsy. I would go with either `print(*iterable, sep=",")` or `print(",".join([str(i) for i in iterable]))`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and create the string you want to print and then print it. Example -

```
print(','.join([str(x) for x in range(5)]))
```

Demo -

```
>>> print(','.join([str(x) for x in range(5)]))
0,1,2,3,4
```

I am using list comprehension above, as that is faster than generator expression , when used with `str.join` .

Comment: `str.join()` would be a good option for generating a custom string from data. However, if we are only passing the string to `print()` then it is not necessary. Just use `print(*iterable, sep=", ")`.

Answer (score 3):

To do that, you can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```
In [1]: print ','.join(map(str,range(5)))
0,1,2,3,4
```

We will need to convert the numbers in `range(5)` to string first to call `str.join()`. We do that using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) operation. Then we join the list of strings obtained from `map()` with a comma `,`.

Answer (score 2):

Another form you can use, closer to your original code:

```
opt_comma="" # no comma on first print
for x in range(5):
    print (opt_comma,x,sep="",end="") # we are manually handling sep and end
    opt_comma="," # use comma for prints after the first one
print() # force new line
```

Of course, the intent of your program is probably better served by the other, more pythonic answers in this thread.  Still, in some situations, this could be a useful method.

Another possibility:

```
for x in range(5):
    if x:
        print (", ",x,end="")
    else:
        print (x, end="")
print()
```

Comment: This is clunky in this particular case, but a very useful technique in more complex cases when you want to have a separator between but not before or after something that you slowly loop your way through.

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in range(5):
    if n == (5-1):
        print(n, end='')
    else:
        print(n, end=',')
```

Comment: I get what you were going for with `5-1`, but it's still a number constant. Would be better to save the list size as a variable then re-use.

Answer (score 0):

An example code:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i != 9:
        print(i, end=", ")
    else:
        print(i)
```

Result:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(5):
    print(x, end=",")
print("\b");
```

Comment: Relying on `\b` to overwrite output is terminal-specific. It will also not overwrite if output is redirected to a file.

Answer (score 0):

1. List item

'''
check if your element is not last ( index = -1 ) and only than add comma:

```
    for i in lista:
        if i != lista[-1]:
            print((i), end= ", ")
    else:
        print((i), end=" ")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).