# How to not print a number in python

Tags: python

```
start = int(input("Enter a number: "))

for number in range(1, start + 1):
    if (number % 2 == 0):
        print("{0}".format(number), end=",")
```

I have this code that prints out the right data but I don't want the input to be in the output and how to I remove the final comma. Plus how do I add the 0 at the beginning? How do I fix this?

Example if I input 10.  The output needs to be 0,2,4,6,8

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - printing out list separated with comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796452/python-printing-out-list-separated-with-comma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from 0 and increasing to 2 may be useful.

```
start = int(input("Enter a number: "))
for number in range(0, start, 2):
    if (number >= start-2):
        print("{0}".format(number))
        break
    print("{0}".format(number), end=",")
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should be what you want I think.

```
start = int(input("Enter a number: "))
numbers = [number for number in range(start) if number%2==0]
print(*numbers, sep=", ")
```

Output

```
0, 2, 4, 6, 8
```

A very similar question has been asked in so. You can find a detailed explanation here
[Python - printing out list separated with comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796452/python-printing-out-list-separated-with-comma)

Answer (score 1):

I would store the results in a list and then `join` them at the end:

```
start = int(input("Enter a number: "))
results = []

for number in range(0, start):
    if (number % 2 == 0):
        results.append(number)

print(",".join(map(str, results)))
```

Comment: I get this error when adding your changes                                                                                                                             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/freed/Desktop/M3L4.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(",".join(results))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: you can't join a string with a list like that.

Comment: @FishingCode right you are. I updated the answer to transform the inputs to string.

Comment: the other simple approach @Freedom220, is to use a `while` loop right after the if statement to prevent including the `start` number i.e. 10 in your format.

Comment: It works great, but how do I remove the final output and comma.

Comment: @Freedom220 Oh, you want to not add the plus one to the `range` method. That's why the last value is getting added. You can also start at zero. Will update

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print(*range(0, start, 2), sep=',')
0,2,4,6,8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
start = int(input("Enter a number: "))

','.join([str(x) for x in range(start) if x % 2 ==0])
```

Result:

```
'0,2,4,6,8'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start = int(input("Enter a number: "))
answer = ''
for number in range(1, start + 1):
    if (number % 2 == 0):
        answer += ("{0},".format(number))
if f"{start}," in answer:
    answer = answer.replace(f",{start},", '')
print(answer)
```