# How do I add a comma after every word in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a problem with my code, so I want my output to be:

```
Baa
Baa, Baa
Baa, Baa, Baa
```

etc. 10 times over

if the input is: `Baa`

This is my code:

```
user_input = str(input("Write something: "))

for i in range(10):
    i += 1
    print(user_input*i)
```

However this only prints:

```
Baa
BaaBaa
BaaBaaBaa
```

And I can't figure out how to add a comma between every word.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - printing out list separated with comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796452/python-printing-out-list-separated-with-comma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce a list with multiple elements by using the `*` operator. Then you can `join()` them together:

```py
for i in range(10):
    print(', '.join([user_input] * (i + 1)))
```