# Prevent trailing comma when printing comma-separated dictionary items

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary `baz`, which is created by zipping the lists `foo` and `bar`:

```
foo = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']
bar = [1, 2, 3]

baz = dict(zip(foo, bar))

baz
{'Blue': 1, 'Red': 2, 'Green': 3}
```

I'd like to be able to print a comma-separated list of keys and values.  To do so, I'm using:

```
for k, v in baz.items():
    print(f'{k} {v}, ', end='')
```

This works, but there is a ***trailing comma*** after the last dictionary value.  What's the best way to remove that comma?

(I tried `sep=','` but doing so removes the commas altogether)

Thanks!

Comment: Use `','.join()` to create comma-separated lists, not a loop.

Comment: @Barmar -- Thank you.   Why doesn't `sep=','` give the desired output (as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796452/printing-a-list-separated-with-commas-without-a-trailing-comma)?

Comment: `sep` is only used when you give multiple arguments to a single `print()` call, it specifies how to separate them. If you just print one thing at a time in a loop, the separator isn't used.