# Is there a way to make a forloop identify it's about to end?

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, newline, string-formatting

Given this code:

```
columns = 12
num = 0
for num in range(0, columns+1):
            print(f"{num:>5d}", end=" ")
```

How can I let the for loop know that this is the last time it will run, so that I can add a newline after the entire output (instead of a space)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the pythonic way to detect the last element in a 'for' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630320/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-detect-the-last-element-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a statement in your loop like:

```
if num == columns:
    print("")
```

to add a line, or add a print("") after the loop.
Like:

```
columns = 12
num=0
for num in range(0, columns+1):
    print(f"{num:>5d}", end=" ")
    if num == columns:
        print("")
```

or

```
columns = 12
num=0
for num in range(0, columns+1):
    print(f"{num:>5d}", end=" ") 
print("")
```