# How do I get - the last element only - of a While Loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

The problem is I get all the elements in the while loop instead of the final result.
Anyone knows how do I get python to insert the last element only in the terminal?

I've tried to insert the result of the following loop:
subtracting 6 from 74, 42 times. The result should be -178 which I get using this code:

```
i = 74
while i > -180:
    print(i)
    i = i - 6
```

I want the result printed in one element (last element) instead of all the numbers leading to -178.

Comment: Move the print statement after the loop?

Comment: @nicomp that prints `-184` in this case, because as written the `print` is called *before* the subtraction. I suppose OP could `print(i + 6)`, but that feels hacky.

Comment: @nicomp, slightly more complicated than that, because after the loop, `i` is `-184`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the pythonic way to detect the last element in a 'for' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630320/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-detect-the-last-element-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = 74
step = 6
while True:
    i = i - step
    if i <= -180:
        i = i + step
        break

print(i) # prints(-178)
```

you can check in if its less than -180 as well.

Comment: If you're going to go this route, I suggest saving `6` or `-6` as a variable named something like `step`.

Comment: thanks @Chris - added the step variable.

Comment: thank you! I got the final element now but "42" the number of times "6" subtracted from the number 74 need to be included in the code to make it a program (i.e if I wanted to subtract 6 from 74 an x time, x being 42 in the previous example.

Answer (score 5):

Move the print to outside the loop. Keep track of the value of `i` *before* the decrement, and then print that variable.

```
i = 74
while i > -180:
    j = i
    i -= 6

print(j)
```

If you just printed `i` after the loop, you'd get `-184`.

Or if you like being really terse:

```
i = 74
while i > -180:
    j, i = i, i - 6

print(j)
```

### Math

If you wish to use a mathematical approach, then you need to get the interval between your start and stop.

```
>>> start = 74
>>> stop = -180
>>> interval = stop - start
>>> interval
-254
```

*Except* that you don't want to go all the way down to -180, so the `stop` should be -179. This gives an interval of -253. The step is -6. If we do integer division, we can find out how many times that step goes into that interval.

```
>>> start = 74
>>> stop = -179
>>> interval = stop - start
>>> step = -6
>>> interval // step
42
```

Now, you just need to multiply that number by the `step` and add that to your start.

```
>>> num_steps = interval // step
>>> start + num_steps * step
-178
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to find the least value that is greater than -180 and whose difference with 74 is a multiple of 6.

No loop is needed for that, as this has a closed formula:

```
i = 74
j = -180  # the limit in your while condition
k = 6     # the step that is subtracted


print(j + 1 + (i - j - 1) % k)  # -178
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop implements a decreasing progression which can be expressed using the range function: `range(74,-180,-6)`.  If you use the `reversed()` function on that range, you'll get the last values to come out first.   Using the `next()` function on that reversed range will get you only the first value that comes out (i.e. the last in your range):

```
print(next(reversed(range(74,-180,-6)))) # -178
```

For a solution that minimally changes your code, you could precompute the next value in your condition on `i` so that the last/extra decrement isn't performed:

```
i = 74
while i - 6 > -180:
    i = i - 6
print(i)
```

Or you can use two variables, one to control the loop (nexti) and one that stores the desired result (i):

```
nexti = i = 74
while nexti > -180:
    i = nexti
    nexti -= 6
print(i)
```