# check for the last element of an iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have for loop like below:

```
for (multimap<string,string>::iterator it2 = ppp.first;it2 != ppp.second; ++it2)
   {
       if(it2==ppp.second -1)
       str=str+it2->second.substr(0,(it2->second).find('-'));
       else
       str=str+it2->second.substr(0,(it2->second).find('-'))+'&';
   }
```

I am using the condition like below:

```
  if(it2==ppp.second -1)
```

for checking the last element and do some additional functionality if i found the last element.But the above condition doesnt work.
it throw's me an error:

```
"000001.cc", line 50: Error: The operation "__rwstd::__rb_tree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>, __rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>>>::iterator - int" is illegal.
1 Error(s) detected.
```

Could anybody please help.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151046/how-can-i-detect-the-last-iteration-in-a-loop-over-stdmap

Comment: @dhruv .Thanks fro the link.it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have not posted the whole code fragment so I am not sure what ppp is but I believe it is something like a pair of iterators. 
The iterator for map does not define the operator-(int val), so you can not use that one. However you can fix the error doing something like this:

```
multimap<string,string>::iterator end_val = ppp.second;
--end_val;
for (multimap<string,string>::iterator it2 = ppp.first;it2 != ppp.second; ++it2)
{
    if(it2==end_val)
    str=str+it2->second.substr(0,(it2->second).find('-'));
    else
    str=str+it2->second.substr(0,(it2->second).find('-'))+'&';
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
end = ppp.second;
std::advance (end, -1);
if (it2 == end) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `ppp` is the multimap, you should get the iterator to the first element by

```
ppp.begin()
```

or

```
ppp.rbegin() // to get a reverse iterator
```

In you loop:

`multimap<string,string>::iterator it2 = ppp.first`

`pp.first` will not give the an iterator, instead it will give the first element of the `pair` helper class `pair<string, string>`